# The Many Memes of Meta

Tags: support, faq, fun, memes

Catchphrases and concepts that spread from person to person are known as [memes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme), which, courtesy the Internet, can now explode across the Earth like a highly contagious virus (hence "going viral"). As with their real-life counterparts, some infectious diseases are global (pandemic), while others are endemic to specific regions.

Stack Overflow, and now even more predominantly Meta Stack Exchange, have seen more than their fair share of these pathological social constructs spread through the user base. They are now ingrained units of our collective culture as SOpedians (a term which I hate, by the way).

Just as travelers' immune systems can be assaulted by new diseases in new places, new users are increasingly likely to be miffed by an ingrained meme and left sitting scratching their heads. I therefore propose that this space be used to document the memes endemic to Stack Exchange's culture.

Each meme should be listed in a separate answer and I hope that we as a community will be able to provide greater context to each one.

**Please actually explain each meme in a way understandable to those not already in the know.** Especially considering that a lot of these memes aren't really understandable to newer users who weren't around in the early years of the network, or are based on system features that no longer exist.

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

### On other Stack Exchange sites

- [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1424)
- [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2187)
- [Anime & Manga](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2474)
- [Information Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/880)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1510)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1289/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6852)
- [Cryptography](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/627)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/the-many-memes-of-worldbuilding)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11750)
- [Politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/the-many-memes-of-politics-and-its-chat)

Comment: Wasn't sure whether to add Joda Time (as the default answer for any Java date/time question). I don't think it really counts as a meme though...

Comment: faq? I'd call this just an aq

Comment: Meh. People ask this stuff? It's merely a q.

Comment: You hate *"SOpedians"*??? I'm going to kill a pony in revenge.

Comment: @Shog9: The a in aq stands for "answered", not "asked" :-)

Comment: Does, the "jump the shark" qualify? What is it all about?

Comment: @Oscar Reyes - "Jump the shark" is a phrase inspired by a popular TV show (Happy Days) when it's main character (Fonzie) was skiing towards a fishy death, only to evade it at the last minute via upwards aerial propulsion. It is used to describe a _deus ex machina_ in a story that seems unrealistic, as if the writer had written him- or herself into a corner and couldn't come up with any feasible way to save the hero. It means the show is out of good ideas and is past its prime, and must use gimmicks (like aquatic carnivore leaping) to draw in audiences. The principle can easily be generalized.

Comment: @Chris - excellent explanation! I've been meaning to find this out but never got around to it.

Comment: Please note: "Jump the shark" has specific meaning in the Jeff/Joel context: see here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000679.html

Comment: What (TF) is "Cultural Height"?  6 ft 2 inches???

Comment: @shog9 has the second comment on @Ben's link. Funny

Comment: @all: I think we should definitely vote up and down these answers, so that everything is in alphabetical order. It's *horrible* to find something.

Comment: This question belongs on Meta-Meta

Comment: @Stu Thompson: Kill another one for me, too.

Comment: This whole page has me laughing out loud.

Comment: There is always the risk that doing so will make all of them non-memes forever. The next time I call a meme a meme, someone will spring up 'Gah! Thats's been *documented*!'

Comment: Meme? a meme is a funny joke with stick figures and funny faces..... curse you wikipedia.

Comment: I don't understand mulching. Can someone please define it?

Comment: You should totally drop those memes and try jQuery.

Comment: needs more jquery +1

Comment: I have used up nearly all of my upvotes on this thread today.

Comment: What about `tl;dr`?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Well, very nice indeed :)

Comment: @Nick, Would **SOers** be preferable to **SOpedians**?

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, users with enough reputation can see deleted posts, so [the link](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5828/32091) is not as dead as you think. PS: Post edits, revision 40

Comment: @Qwertiy it's dead for 99% of the users here.

Comment: I'm very concerned no one has posted Obligatory xkcd as an answer, but I'm also too lazy to do all the documentation on it.

Comment: @anonymous2 the list of sites is only for posts on that site's *own* Meta, written in the same spirit as this one.

Comment: @Glorfindel oops, thanks for the correction.  :)

Comment: So this is why I sometimes get random comments, but what about random down votes? Seems like some people took things out of context.

Comment: I love this question so much. Every time I get a bunch of downvoting on Meta SE I just come here and remember why I want to live ;-)

Comment: Btw I use arch and you should really try jQuery

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Voting the list into alphabetical order would prove we are capable of a high level of cooperation. (It sets the bar too high to actually try it, I think)

Comment: The newest meme on the town is to probably resign as a moderator.

Comment: @ToddWilcox “Obligatory xkcd” isn’t exclusive to Stack Exchange, is it?

Comment: We're gonna need a bigger boat.

Comment: Can anyone explain what this thread is about?

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) has their [own set of memes](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/whats-a-zombie-and-what-are-the-many-other-memes-of-code-review/1511#1511) (currently 35)—though the title of it is slightly misleading.

Answer (score 819):

**Meme**: Jon Skeet

**Originator**: [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

**Cultural Height**: Every Day. Ever.

**Background**: Jon Skeet is an avid user of Stack Overflow, whose many answers (primarily in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)) earned him [over a million reputation points](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/). This makes him the top-ranked SO user.

**Related**: [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Comment: He even gets the most upvotes as a meme!!

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks surpassed Jon Skeet, it only took 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Jon Skeet is now above 6 to 8 weeks, and it did not take 6 to 8 weeks. Only Jon Skeet can bypass this rule!

Comment: I thought Mum Skeet was the originator of Jon?...

Comment: @Locutus: Jon Skeet coded himself in lisp so that he could go on to invent assembly language.

Comment: John Skeet is a computer programmer program (which programs computer programmer programs).

Comment: Jon Skeet is the new Chuck Norris meme? Amazing sure, but why the caveman idolatry? Skeet skeet.

Comment: Once, I told my friend about Jon and he was so impressed, he googled it. But he made one major fatal mistake he never expected...He typed "Jon" as "John". To no surprise, our entire district was blacklisted by Google.

Comment: As of May 2015, I can safely say, **You Know Nothing, John Skeet**

Comment: @9kSoft Ok, you've gotta tell us what you're talking about. Did you beat him at Jeopardy or something?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard its a Game of Thrones refrence, of the meme, "You know nothing John Snow"

Comment: @9kSoft Ok. I got it. I mean I get that it's a reference; that I needed it explained to me that it is a reference means I don't get the reference, but that's neither here nor there. Thank you. (So you probably only needed to tell me what you're talking about. I'm sure everyone else got it already.)

Comment: Avatar: The Last Airbender, Book 2: Earth, Episode 14 at 7:40: "Great news! Your request [to report urgent information that could change the course of the war] will be processed earlier than usual... 6 to 8 weeks actually!"

Comment: And now Jon Skeet is the first user to hit 1 million reputation: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/

Comment: They invented the yottabyte to hold Jon Skeet's reputation.

Comment: Now even jQuery uses JonSkeet under the hood.

Comment: Should have made the cultural height Jon skeets height

Comment: @Lordology [They invented even larger metric prefixes](https://www.livescience.com/new-metric-measurement-prefixes) just so that we can quantify his reputation using a ronnabyte and a quettabyte.

Answer (score 688):

**Meme**: jQuery

**Originator**: Unknown (possibly [Ólafur Waage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22459/olafur-waage))

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: A Stack Overflow-centric meme, jQuery began its career early on as the answer to beat for any question that even remotely referenced JavaScript. Its popularity became so great that eventually jQuery became the default answer to any potential question on Stack Overflow [no matter how ridiculous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif).

**Usage**: "Hey, I see you are trying to connect to that Oracle database using C++. You should totally drop that and try jQuery."

**See Also**: [Greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19495#19495) (Meta Stack Overflow equivalent)

[image]

Comment: I see you're trying to blame me for a meme. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: I'd like to point out that since 1.4 dropped the answer to every jQuery question has been to use the new $.live() functionality.

Comment: have you guys seen this? http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif (http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Comment: omg that screenshot is priceless :D

Comment: That picture is why I no longer participate actively on Stack Overflow...

Comment: [Link to that hilarious jQuery question (add number with jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603/add-a-number-to-another-number-in-javascript)

Comment: It's deleted :(

Comment: I think jQuery is the way to bring this question back.

Comment: I bet the screenshot by @JeffAtwood was made using jQuery, perhaps with some Greasemonkey included.

Comment: jQuery? Use Python! (It has `import antigravity`!)

Comment: @Xeoncross's question doesn't seem to have a jQuery answer anymore. In fact, I searched and the word "jQuery" isn't on that page at all. Also the number adding question seems to have been deleted again.

Comment: So, would "jQuery all the things" be a meme squared? *I know, I know.....lame.*

Comment: jQuery already supports jQuerying all the things. `$("*")`.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GzHRf.png

Comment: We have another prime example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34418769/746736

Comment: Wow. The question is real.

Comment: Not enough jQuery -1

Comment: There’s a more modern in-steroids version of this meme (or its root cause). In simple CSS questions, many people will suggest using Bootstrap to solve ANY problem. And not only adding Bootstrap styles, but the whole package: jQuery, Bootstrap JS, and Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Why is that precious question deleted? It should be undeleted and locked for historical significance.

Comment: Does anyone know who the original author of the screenshot is?

Comment: What on earth is jQuery?

Comment: I reposted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052172/how-to-add-a-number-to-another-number-in-javascript

Comment: @Hjulle The only real user in the page is Bobince, and the questions other than jQuery are about parsing HTML with regular expressions, which he or she posted a [famous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216029/38765) to. So I think it's either Bobince, or a fan.

Comment: What's even funnier is that the legit answer got downvoted :-)

Comment: The related questions on that screenshot are gold too.

Comment: @Zackary yep, it's hilarious!

Comment: @ÓlafurWaage I see you’re trying to be funny. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: This question is still live on the internet: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2694603/21493925

Answer (score 655):

**Meme:** 6 to 8 Weeks

**Originator:** [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

**First Heard:** May 13th, 2008

**Cultural Height:** In about 6 to 8 weeks

**Definition:** The time estimate given "off the top of my head" when the Stack Overflow team has only a vague idea of how long a task will take because they have little-to-no formal scheduling or even a list of tasks.

**Background:**

*Taken from the transcript of [Podcast 005](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-5/), from 03 min 18 secs*

> **Atwood:** Some people have been asking about scheduling, and I want to
>   clarify, I've been telling people six
>   to eight weeks until we get to what we
>   call our private beta of
>   Stack Overflow […] and
>   I've also been getting some very very
>   nice emails from people that want to
>   help in some way and contribute, and
>   I've been inviting those people into
>   our private beta later on. So—
>
> **Spolsky:** Wait how do you invite what? Through what mechanism do you
>   invite them into our private beta?
>
> **Atwood:** Basically they email me directly and then, I add them to the
>   list. And then six weeks from now—
>
> **Spolsky:** Oh. And you have like a notepad file type thing.
>
> **Atwood:** Pretty much, it's just a basic text file. But yeah, it's hard
>   to manage having a bunch of people
>   contributing at this point, cause
>   we're still in very much the formative
>   of stages. But certainly once we get
>   into private beta, I want tons of
>   people to look at it and provide
>   feedback at that point. So if you can
>   postpone your desire for about six
>   weeks, uh, we'll get you.
>
> **Spolsky:** So how do you get this 6 to 8 weeks? What's this based on? Did
>   you like make some tasks that you want
>   to complete?
>
> **Atwood:** uh no, I er… That's just sort of… off the top of my head.
>
> **Spolsky:** [laughs] Well okay, you're doomed Jeff. There's some
>   controversy. You, sir, are doomed,
>   because you don't know what things you
>   have to do.
>
> **Atwood:** Yes. I know, I know.

**Reference:** [Podcast 005](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-5/)

**Related:** [What is the origin of "6 to 8 weeks" and is it really the Crazy Frog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog)

Comment: @David: In Sim Copter, it might *not* have been a joke (though most of the other messages shown during loading certainly are).

Comment: It's like Thomas Friedman's 6 months (http://www.fair.org/index.php?page=2884).

Comment: I just watched [Madagascar 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madagascar_2) in German - and the penguins said when asked how long it will take to fix the plane after the crash: "Oh, we should be ready in about 6 to 8 months..." Coincidence? ;)

Comment: Wow, Jeff Atwood takes more fake hypothetical time to implement things than Jick (of KoL). Kingdom of Loathing has exactly the same meme, except in Jicktime, it's "2 weeks".

Comment: @SamB I really want to know what Sim Copter reference you were responding to.

Comment: BTW, [private beta began](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/) 11 weeks later, on July 31, '08. Atwood said at the time that it would last "anywhere from two weeks to a month," and it ending up being [five weeks](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html).

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: I can only assume someone named David said something about "reticulating splines"

Comment: http://smbc-comics.com/comics/20121111after.gif

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know that occurrences of this meme from elsewhere could be collected here. In that case: [Empty Data Centre - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSwfylSrCVY&t=1m34s)

Comment: Does anyone remember there was a web app that helped you "estimate" development time by asking you "How many developers are working on it? How many lines of code is the app? How many vending machines are available to the developers?" and it had a slider bar after each one. And no matter what you put, it spit out "6 - 8 weeks"

Comment: [At 16:00 in this _Drawn Together_ episode](https://youtu.be/DN1Lx9hKCoA?t=16m) they won some sort of prize after “6 – 8 weeks”. I honestly wonder where they got that from… normally you’d know exactly how long it took if the waiting time is already over.

Comment: Thanks very much for curbing my expectations! I'll look for this project to come out sometime next year... :-)

Comment: @Spontifixus it's actually [6 to 9 months](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMV59-CBGrI)... and it was the first thing I thought of when reading this also.

Comment: @JeffC in German it's "Sechs oder acht Monate. - Sechshundertacht Monate?" Literally translating to "Six or eight months. - Sixhundredeight months?!"

Comment: @MattSayar it's not online anymore. But you can find it here http://web.archive.org/web/20100202011937/http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php

Comment: Solid detective work @jfrej! How did you find it??

Comment: The Wikipedia page of "Dartmouth workshop" says "The project lasted approximately 6 to 8 weeks". Coincidence? I THINK NOT!

Comment: Hey Robert. Are you in *serious* need of reputation (Sep 1)?

Comment: @iDebug With the addition of suggested edits, Community Wiki has been all but depreciated, but the consensus is that nobody's post should be forced to Community Wiki. I think it is a needless feature.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Hi,employee. I agree with you. Now can I own [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299166/350567)?

Comment: The Cultural Height made me chuckle

Comment: @iBug, RobertCartaino Cheaters!...

Comment: [Direct link to the audio](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-73) (now (officially) hosted at SoundCloud). It is at 03 min 18 secs - 05 min 05 secs.

Comment: @MattSayar There's a similar one at [sixtoeightweeks.com](https://sixtoeightweeks.com/), which has been around since at least 2009.

Answer (score 552):

**Meme**: Freehand Circles

**Originator**: [TheTXI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22164/thetxi)

**Cultural Height**: TBD

[image: (freehand-circled text) Background: Whenever screenshots are submitted, it is good practice to try and point the user to what you are talking about through the usage of arrows and shapes to lead one's eye. The greatest of these tools is the circle, and it has become customary to give cheap upvotes to users who painstakingly draw circles free hand and do not rely on lazy shape tools that give soulless circles devoid of personality. It has also become customary to unjustly punish users who refrain from using freehand circles, or who eschew the practice of circling important information altogether.¶ The effectiveness of freehand circles to illustrate screenshots can be further augmented via the usage of drop shadows. It has been shown that special combinations of freehand circles and drop shadows in unison have led to spontaneous erotic climax.]

**Variation**: during Winter Bash season, some members substitute the freehand circles for freehand hats. Unlike the hats, they won't disappear after Winter Bash is over.

**See Also**: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/random-sorting-appears-to-screw-with-answer-permalinks), [and Here as answer to *this* post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/159533)

Comment: I find the circle tool accomplishes the task faster than using the freehand tool. ... We're not designers!

Comment: @chakrit: You have no soul.

Comment: Memo to self: Use the pen instead of the mouse to draw circles, that way they have a soul *and* can look great at the same time.

Comment: Ultimate combination: freehand circle and arrow, with drop shadow, on a picture with faded torn edge borders (themselves with drop shadow!). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295414/how-to-open-a-file-in-eclipse-and-jump-to-a-specific-line/2296043#2296043

Comment: I like [scary monks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39782/javascript-tag-showing-up-as-javas-on-main-page) much better!

Comment: ...I couldn't help myself.  This post needed more freehand circles.

Comment: Made me think of Steve Lord's famous SirJester quote- Auditor "are you trying to run rings round me?"; SirJester "Of course not, these are COBIT compliant control ellipses"

Comment: Here's the link to the now deleted revision of the link most recently removed in the example list: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5295/1

Comment: I think we should have a built in tool to allow us to draw freehand circles. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20726/drawing-sketching-tool-for-elaborating-questions) post proposes the feature request, but never received an answer (confirm or decline tag)

Comment: @Joey: I've got a Wacom graphics tablet for that :)

Comment: Is it frowned upon to use colors other than red?

Comment: Feature request for image editors: Freehand-Looking circle tool.

Comment: @Yawus Yes.​​​
​
​
​

Comment: Humbug, it's too much work!  When I do crude circles, I do it in Illustrator, *start* with a circle, and it takes a half hour painstakingly reshaping the splines to look drunk and mouse-drawn.

Comment: [This meme has evolved beyond our wildest dreams - Introducing Freehand fingertip!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179713/54887)

Comment: Is this meme talking about [**me**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59561/find-four-pins-of-50-in-this-image-a-hidden-object-puzzle/59563#comment182202_59563)?

Comment: @Gaelan though this may be a bit late, you can now generate freehand-looking circles using JavaScript: https://github.com/pshihn/rough

Comment: Recently the arrows have become really crazy, e.g. [\[1\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325242/289905), [\[2\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381230/4642212), or even [a tentacle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381231/4642212).

Comment: The sample image is not representative. It doesn't exemplify using freehand circles to show where the important spot is in a screenshot.

Comment: This entry is now devoid of any explanation of what it is. Which is a pity as it is the most useful entry to reference when encountering confusing, unclear, and busy screenshots without any clear indication of what is important and what is not important.

Answer (score 274):

**Meme:** Two problems.

**Originator:** Unknown (the quote itself is by Jamie Zawinski)

**Cultural Height:** Neverending

**Background:** A quotation by Jamie Zawinski goes like this:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

There are many questions on Stack Overflow relating to regular expressions, and many answers that suggest regular expressions. In a lot of cases, a regular expression is simply not necessary or even useful. Hence the phrase, "Now you have two problems," usually posted as a comment.

**Examples:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938065/how-to-match-a-string-of-a-certain-length-with-a-regex), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82064/a-regex-for-version-number-parsing/82152#82152), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332590/html-comment-scraping-in-php/1332640#1332640), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061365/help-with-building-regex-to-extract-text-of-html-tag), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300936/recognize-synonyms-of-regex-in-question-title#comment230155_300936).

A regular expression question also [caused the breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) of a Stack Overflow member.

Comment: meh, I don't really consider this a meme of SO or meta

Comment: Why only 5 ups? This is one of the funniest memes here.

Comment: @Nathan That answer has **4351 upvotes**. (It would probably have more, but it's been locked.)

Comment: [Random picture.](http://i.imgur.com/AHavg.png)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: Intriguingly, this can now no longer be named in question titles, because of the 'problem' filter . . .

Comment: that username...

Comment: See also http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 where Jeffrey Friedl attempts to track down the origin of the meme.  It seems to be such old folklore that we can't really tell where it comes from.  Definitely older than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn't know the Meme, but I used a similar Wording (and definitely Meaning) in a [Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info): "*[...] Same Recommendation when selecting the `regex` Tag along with the `iMacros` one, but, hum..., `regex` is (nearly) "never" the "Best" Solution with `iMacros`, there are "always" better Solutions [...]*"... // Next time the Tag Wiki needs an Edit/Revision, I might mention "two problems" and link to this Meme, ah-ah...!

Answer (score 272):

**Meme**: Unicorns (née Ponies)

**Originator**: [TheTXI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22164/thetxi)

**Cultural Height**: April 1st, 2009

**Background**: The pony meme began without fanfare early in TheTXI's time as a member of Stack Overflow. Its first recorded usages can be traced back to long-running comment threads and arguments on both Stack Overflow and User Voice. The comment "I like ponies" would be interjected into threads, seemingly at random, which inevitably led to those threads getting completely derailed.

Before long, it became evident that TheTXI was not the only SOpedian who found ponies to be the most wonderfullest things **ever**. Ponies' popularity grew to the point where Jeff Atwood and the Stack Overflow development team implemented the Cornify button on all questions and answers for April Fools' Day 2009. From there, the popularity of ponies — and their magical weaponized form, unicorns — grew exponentially.

**Other Official References**:
For April Fools' Day 2010, all avatar requests were sent to [Unicornify](https://web.archive.org/web/20110224234102/http://unicornify.appspot.com/) instead of Gravatar, resulting in every user having a personal unicorn for the day.

On April Fools' Day 2011, voting on questions triggered [unicorn animations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85617/can-we-get-a-gallery-of-unicorns).

On April Fools' Day 2012, the [Clippycorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyHgm.png), a parody to Clippy [Microsoft Office Assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant), was appearing at [various conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127704/578924) offering users a semi-joke tips on site usage.

For April Fools' Day 2014, unicoins were added to stack, allowing users to mine coins that could then be used to purchase different powers for use on stack sites. [What are Stack Overflow unicoins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins)

For April Fools' Day 2019, a [time machine version of SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine) was created to show how the site would have looked should it have been around in 1998. A unicorn was included in the page's background as well as ASCII art in the HTML source.

**Related**: In 2006, for April Fools' Day, Slashdot [switched to a pink ponies theme](http://news.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=06/03/31/1644225). This subsequently led to an ["OMG Ponies"](http://slashdot.org/tags/omgponies) Slashdot meme.

Comment: @TheTXI: Friend of yours? http://stackoverflow.com/users/27457/pitadev

Comment: Jon B - That is a unicorn, not a pony. They are very different.

Comment: Unicorns are magical ponies.

Comment: Unicorns are the magically weaponized form of a pony.

Comment: Sunshine and sparkles are their weapons.

Comment: obligatory link to http://i-want-a-pony.com/

Comment: Unicorns are not magical ponies.  They are a cross between a horse, a goat, a lion, and a narwhale (or something with a horn).  A true unicorn has a goat's beard and a lion's tail.  The equine part is horse, not pony.  Unicorns aren't cute, they are dangerous.

Comment: There is an answer on SO with 1600 plus upvotes. Could this be mainly because it mentions ponies, in a beautifully subliminal way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @MarkJ: No, it's because it was featured on digg & codinghorror, and was actually modeled after the madmen often featured in HP Lovecraft's writings. However, in its sublime madness, it brought in many (MANY) SO in-jokes, and that probably did contribute to the orgy of upvote love.

Comment: Back in the days Last.fm still had a soul, one of the last.fm  todo features was a free pony.

Comment: SO has lost it's soul. No hidden ponies!

Comment: @boris callens - my ISP has a free pony as it's number 2 most popular idea on the todo list (and a moon on a stick at #5).

Comment: I can't believe that was the 2009 April Fool's day thing...curse you time!

Comment: "Sunshine and sparkles are their weapons" - Looks like they're in league with the Pyros

Comment: Added an edit to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn#External_links

Comment: It's not "I like ponies." It's "I like trains."

Comment: After April 1, I was searching **like crazy** for that Unicoins sign! No wonder!

Comment: ..is the ponyoverflow link still related? It's a japanese page with no picture of ponies nor unicorns... wayback machine doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Yaaaaay candy mountain charlieeeeeee

Comment: What's "TheTXI"?

Comment: http://i-want-a-pony.com/ appears to be down :( here's what you would have seen: http://web.archive.org/web/20131016021910/http://i-want-a-pony.com/IWantAPony.jpg

Comment: The link to Unicornify is broken, did someone kill all the ponies?

Comment: This should be updated with the unicorn that appeared when you zoom out on this year's April Fools

Comment: Is "SOpedian" an officially endrosed term?

Answer (score 264):

**Meme:** `plzsendtehcodez`

**Originator:** [TheDailyWTF](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez), as [documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend/10086#10086).

**First Use of Tag**: [Documented Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend/10987#10987).

**Cultural Height:** Unknown

**Background:** The [plzsendtehcodez](/questions/tagged/plzsendtehcodez) tag was predominantly used on SO to label questions with some variant of the phrase "please send the codes" present in the language of the question, or more generally any homework question directly copied from an assignment without any attempt made by the original poster to solve it himself.

It is now [considered bad practice to apply the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend/10086#10086) to a question and users should remove it as necessary.

Comment: Periodically a new variant will pop up, perhaps in a misguided attempt to eventually gain the Taxonomist badge.

Comment: I did it once as a misguided attempt at humor... :(

Comment: [I am not sure if I should be upset, indifferent, or delighted that PHP is the only survivor of this meme.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYXki.png)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus wow this is sad

Comment: @mousetail: What was the intent?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Make the link point to the actual article instead of requiring you to go to another post to find the link

Answer (score 258):

**Meme:** Fastest Gun in the West (FGITW)

**Originator:** [Omer van Kloeten](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/132257)

**First Heard:** September 11th, 2008

**Definition:** A problem identified as a side-effect of sorting votes by descending score where first-posted answers are quickly up-voted, trumping vote opportunities for people who sit down and answer a question in a long, thorough way.

**Background:** This problem was originally identified on UserVoice.com and reposted to meta.stackexchange.com here: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Whether the FGITW problem is actually a problem has been a source of controversy. Many considered it a feature — get fast answers, by design. Various solutions were suggested including this one ([Randomly reorder all answers posted within 10 minutes of each other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/randomly-reorder-all-answers-posted-within-10-minutes-of-each-other)), which was eventually implemented, inciting another protest labeled "[The Slowest Cheater in the East (SCITE) problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19535#19535)".

Comment: This is not a meme, this is just an acronym.

Comment: A meme is a catchphrase or concept. "Fastest Gun in the West" qualifies on both accounts (which just happens to have a convenient acronym).

Comment: Or is it an initialism? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism

Comment: @Christopher Galpin: Agreed.  FGITW is an initialism (is not pronounced as a word, cf. MVC, PHP), SCITE is an acronym (can be pronounced as a word, cf. NATO, laser).

Comment: I beg to differ. Fuh-Get-Wuh. (Actually, the last syllable would probably be better represented with a schwa.) C'mon, we're computer guys, we pronounce every initialism! (Hello, WSDL?)

Comment: @JohnRudy I pronounce it as fgitw.

Comment: @John Rudy: Yes, like [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) (as *"Tim Toady"*)

Answer (score 220):

## This meme is officially deprecated.

**Please do not use this meme. It remains here while links to it are still quite 'out in the wild' as a reference to inform folks that they shouldn't be using it, and should be flagging comments linking to it for removal.**

While at the time it was seen as light-hearted fun, that context (and Jeff) are long gone; the use of this is just confusing and definitely not in line with our [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

---

**Meme:** Pluralization Bug (aka Jeff Atwood's giant S)

**Originator:** [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

**Cultural Height:** Past

**First Seen:** [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)

**Background:** Originally seen on Twitter [here](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105), Jeff made his feeling clear about user posting pluralization bug by saying

> Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

It has since been used as a response to numerous post about pluralization and is the default accepted answer.

Also known as Jeff Atwood's giant S, [for example](/q/305311/350567).

See Also:

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times), [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694), [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15590/are-negative-numbers-singular-or-plural), [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/spell-fix-in-user-profile-1-questions) and [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89149/the-your-flagging-history-block-uses-the-plural-when-the-number-of-flags-is-1/89151#89151) or the tag [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals)

Comment: I think you mean "numerous *posts*".

Comment: "I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death" is in blatant violation of the Be Nice policy, and even more so of the new CoC. Just because he is the co-founder of the site doesn't mean he can freely abuse people. "We won't fix pluralization issues for now. We have limited development time and would like to spend it on other more rewarding features." or something along those lines would have been adequate.

Comment: @MaskedMan Agreed, we'll deprecate it. I've added a notice to the top, feel free to flag anything you see linking to it as obsolete for removal. If we just remove it without a note, it'll just cause confusion.

Comment: @TimPost I’m case you haven’t read it yet, I’ve posted a meta question asking for clarification of this ban: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338952/clarification-on-the-ban-of-the-meme-about-pluralization-bugs

Answer (score 172):

**Meme:** Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

**Originator:** [badp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13992/badp), made popular by [rchern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140548/rchern) in a [comment on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65838/stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-header-thingy-usability-question#comment157354_65838)

**First Seen:** [27 Sept. 2010](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown)

**Cultural Height:** `margin-top: 6px;`

**Definition:** [image]

**Variants:**

- Stack Exchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™ ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69237/), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69230/))
- Stack Exchange™ ChronoWarping ChatCombinator™ ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67727/))
- Stack Exchange™ PeopleEmpowering Diamond-O-Matic™ ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71777/) - **deleted**)

**Related:**

- Stack Exchange™ SuperCollider MicroDashboard™ ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82538/2509) - **deleted**)
- Stack Exchange™ SuperCollider Freehand Circle™ Editor ([1](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor))

Comment: Please move quickly to the StackExchange, as the effects of prolonged exposure to the SuperDropdown are not part of this test.

Comment: I keep telling you... exposure to the MultiColider SuperDropdown is not a part of this test. >:|

Comment: @Jonathan: The cultural height line was balpha's edit. And I like it, too.

Comment: Also see:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775

Comment: This comment is intended to make @TheTXI happier by making TheTXI click the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™.

Comment: *MultiCollider* - could this possibly be an oblique reference to the Fountains of Wayne song "Supercollider"? In which case there is meme spinoff potential here.

Comment: Is there any reason for "Stack Exchange" to have a space in the middle?  The referenced question doesn't have a space.

Answer (score 156):

**Meme**: Burninated
[image: Original burnination image] [image: New graphics]

**Originator**: Possibly [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) / [Strong Bad: Trogdor the Burninator](https://homestarrunner.com/sbemail58.html) ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90X5NJleYJQ&rel=0&modestbranding=1))

**Cultural Height**: 2010 - …

**Background**: Used in reference to deleting a tag from the system.

**See Also**: [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request), [I made us some Trogdor graphics!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121570), ["TROGDOR!" Flash game](https://homestarrunner.com/trogdor).

Comment: Oh wow, the whole time I thought Jeff or someone else on the team made up that drawing as the pluralization mascot turned tag deleter.

Comment: Also addressed at [The true meaning of burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/the-true-meaning-of-burninate) (but the answer is basically just this answer, copy-pasted)

Comment: You can now purchase a figure of Trogdor with [this board game](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/4212282/trogdor-board-game).

Answer (score 155):

**Meme:** Eeeek!

**Originator:** [Marti](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/153019/marti)

**First Seen:** [4 Mar. 2011 ~ Eeeek what happened to my envelope?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope) (10k only). Screenshot for <10K users:

[image: Eeeek! What happened to my envelope? The envelope is gone from next to my name! How am I supposed to check where those recent points came from? I don't remember the link to that page! Edit: just to summarize the ways that the reputation graph does not make a suitable replacement for the /recent page • The recent page has just the information I'm interested in, front and center. The graph hides the list of recent rep changes at the bottom of the page, below a bunch of noise, and it only shows the time period I'm interested in if it feels like it and/or I beg and plead. • Not to mention, if the time period I'm interested in does not happen to coincide with a UTC calendar day, I'm SOL. • The recent page also includes comments that are new to me. With this new setup, that's in an entirely different place (Responses tab of profile), at least 3 clicks away from the main page. (And a bunch of scrolling followed by a click away from the rep changes, if I've finally gotten them to show.) • The recent page showed me only the things that were new to me, and all of the things that were new to me. On the Responses tab, I have to remember which activity I've already seen, but that's still better than the rep graph, on which it is completely impossible to see where those most recent reputation changes came from, because 1 whole day is as fine-grained as it gets. • Being able to sort the rep changes by timestamp instead of grouping them would only be a partial fix: there's still the issue of 1-UTC-calendar-day-increments, and again, I'd have to remember where I was last. Edit 2: The MicroDashboard totally misses the point. The most useful feature of the /recent page is that it remembers where you were. Unless you tell it otherwise, it only shows the newest changes, the ones you haven't seen yet. Even the new graphless reputation page doesn't do that. (Take the bug tag off all you want, that doesn't change the fact that something that used to work now no longer does.)]

**Cultural Height:** Probably still to be reached, given the increase of developers working for Stack Exchange. Although see comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83774/153019) for first signs of possible decline (2 weeks after first appearance).

**Definition:** Stack Overflow developers like to change things, just for the heck of it. This can be shocking for users, who find their site suddenly *different* in some way. Cherished envelopes go missing, then cherished posts complaining about cherished envelopes going missing go missing, then posts complaining about the missing posts go missing (sometimes before they're even given time to be cherished!).

The inevitable response to this shock is a high-pitched squeal, aptly captured in the title prefix, "Eeek!" (See FAQ section for proper spelling.)

**Origin:** Once upon a time Stack Exchange 2.0 supported a site-specific notification system to find all the things that had happened to your account since the last time you logged in to that one site. [It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63847/favourites-changed-notification-doesnt-work-properly) [was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18396/should-recent-icon-be-changed) [supposedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26855/what-is-the-logic-behind-users-recent-xxxxx-versus-users-xxxxx-username) [horrid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68387/the-envelope-icon-driving-me-mad-with-false-positives) [and](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61012/any-progress-with-the-envelope-indicator) [lots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67236/ux-restrictions-of-stack-overflow) [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/please-notify-us-when-a-question-we-ask-or-answer-is-closed-or-reopened) [people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82922/envelope-still-present-at-area51) [hated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67701/envelope-highlighted-but-no-responses) [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78708/notification-envelope-deprecated). The SEI staff removed it so they could implement a new feature. People FREAKED OUT. I'm pretty sure that when [Vesuvius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Vesuvius) [blew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruption_of_Mount_Vesuvius_in_79) that the people took it less hard than the users on Stack Exchange 2.0 sites freaked out over this new change.

Since then, [several other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83615/eeeek-what-happened-to-the-eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope-question) [topics have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go) [been raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked) with similar titles [and topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83286/can-more-of-the-functionality-of-the-old-envelope-be-added-to-the-new-drop-down-m).

**FAQ**

- *[I'm wondering if the correct form of Eeeek! is four letters e or five.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/693081#693081)*
- [The number of e's in Eeeek is variable.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/693228#693228) [Ideally, it should correspond](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/695181#695181) to the level of eeekiness of the problem. For example, a [minor CSS tweak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked) that affects only one page of one site should warrant no more than an 'Ek', while a true bug such as the meme originator or [the first signs that SO is achieving sentience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83748/153019) can take 'Eeeek'. A longer squeal should be reserved for truly earth-shattering problems; please resist the urge for eeek-inflation.

Comment: All the people who hated the envelope with a passion hated its **appearance** only. The page it linked to was (and until it's deleted, still is) probably *the* most useful part of the UI.

Comment: @Marti then I presume you have not looked at the new replacement features?

Comment: Sure I have. In all umpteen of the different places I have to look.

Comment: So to anyone reading this who _hasn't_ read the edit revision log, you should. And the point of this thread in general is comedy. This post is not intended to be a dig at anyone, and is satire. Also, the regulars here know they can find me in chat most of the time. TTYL.

Comment: @drachenstern: there, is that better? :D

Comment: @Marti ~ I don't know, I kinda liked the crowdsourced improvements. And I collided with you so I reverted to your revert. How odd that we hit within seconds ... serendipity?

Comment: @drachenstern: that's one word for it, I guess. And I got shiny new Cleanup badge out of it. Tee hee.

Comment: How long until this gets burnified?

Comment: @Wikis three more days?

Comment: or should I have said 6 - 8 weeks?

Comment: @drachenstern You mean 6-8 weeeeeks? Ba-dum ching.

Comment: Too much Eeeeking in Stack *Eeekxchange*!

Comment: Interesting.. if you have less than 10k rep it just shows you a Page Not Found?

Answer (score 155):

**Meme:** Parsing HTML with RegEx

**Originator:** [Bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince)

**Cultural Height:** <strike>Un</strike>**tl̕L H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝**S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

**Background:** This meme began as bobince has unofficially become the Assistant Don't Parse HTML With Regex Officer. He has described the terrible maw of horrors that will uproar if HTML is ever parsed with RegEx, such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Isn't this a part of the Zalgo meme around the Internet?

Comment: @Texenox Yes it is... as far as I know.

Comment: @nine But the relation between Zalgo, RegEx and HTML is specific to Stack Overflow.

Comment: No mention of Pony the Tony? :-(

Comment: @val It's actually Tony the Pony. ;-)

Answer (score 137):

**Meme:** Twitter-driven development (also occasionally called Twittergate)

**Origin:** <s>[Meta Stack Exchange on revisiting the Hot Network Questions feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934/282465)</s> Twitter

**Cultural height:** Whenever a feature is proposed or a bug is reported

**Background:** In April 2018, a Medium post detailing issues with Stack Overflow's issues with welcoming new users was shared on Twitter, and that tweet eventually led to the *Welcoming* initiative, resulting in noticeable changes to the site, including a revised comment flagging form, a new [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/), and the [New Contributor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/282465) banners. In October 2018, another tweet resulted in the development team quickly preventing the Interpersonal Skills site from providing questions to the Hot Network Questions list, while initiating a [call for reforming said list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934/282465).

These events contributed to the impression that Twitter is a better place to propose changes and features for the Stack Exchange network than the respective Meta sites.

**Examples of use:**

> - The correct way to report a problem is to use a Stack Exchange account and report on Meta Stack Exchange.
> - That's not the correct way! The correct way, if you want change, is to complain on Twitter! Meta discussions do nothing.

> These are great suggestions. Someone should post them on Twitter.

Comment: About time someone made that meme official. ;)

Comment: I think it is me who coined this meme [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316904/which-sites-are-excluded-or-penalized-from-hot-network-questions/316906#comment1038466_316906 "'haven't you heard of TDD methodology? Twitter-driven development'")

Comment: @gnat That seems to be accurate. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/927981/twitter) reveals the [first use of the meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316904/which-sites-are-excluded-or-penalized-from-hot-network-questions/316906#comment1038247_316906), and some time later [your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316904/which-sites-are-excluded-or-penalized-from-hot-network-questions/316906#comment1038466_316906) defines "Twitter-driven development". Feel free to add this information to the post if you find it relevant enough. :)

Comment: It wasn't a short Twitter post in April that led to the Welcoming initiative. It was a long-form Medium post.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog This is debatable. The way I see it, the blog post was at least partially caused by the tweet.

Answer (score 118):

**Meme**: Waffles

**Originator**: [Eric](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/95589/eric)

**Cultural Height**: Late August – Early September, 2009

**Background**: Eric just really likes waffles, and apparently so does everyone else who has even a shred of decent humanity. Those who do not like waffles may also be vampires and haters of all things pony-related.

Here's how Eric [has explained it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19559/578924):

> 1. I *love* waffles. I had some this morning for breakfast. Effing delicious, man.
> 2. [It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/5-tags-is-too-few/13915#13915) was in response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/5-tags-is-too-few), which wasn't a question at all. The OP made an assertion without any backing, so I stated my opinion with as much backing. I needed to make the 15 characters, so I said, "You know what, I'm going to spread my love of waffles." And so I have.

In an ensuing discussion regarding the delicious food, users were put in the penalty box for a day. There are conflicting reports that allege moderator abuse — perhaps, an anti-waffle agenda — and others who believe this was due to over-zealousness on the part of the suspended. Tragically, because most of the comments were deleted, a proper historical account is difficult to build.

It is also likely a reference to Oolong, a well-known Internet phenomenon:

> "[Oolong (rabbit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oolong_(rabbit)) – a bunny trained to balance objects on its head. Famous for balancing pancakes and waffles, it has become a meme similar to lolcats." — From [Lolcat # See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolcat#See_also)

**See Also**: [Meta SO 404 page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/404) — [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174/waffles) — [The Official Stack Overflow Bunny](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45238)

Comment: ........... I Love

Comment: So do ...

http://blog.ericandrade.com/when-muppets-get-stoned-they-eat-waffles-waff

Comment: [Another waffle reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135606/are-mso-questions-deleted-too-fast) Jun 12, 2012.

Comment: i thought oolong was a genre for a Tea.

Comment: I don't like waffles.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ You're a menace to society.

Comment: waffles waffles waffles

Comment: It takes true dedication to keep a username for 12 years to preserve a meme reference. Waffle?

Answer (score 109):

**Meme:** Boat Programming

**Origin:** Santiago

**Cultural Height:** Discussed on both [the podcast](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29044) and [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/joke-questions-please-refrain/).

**Background:** [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about).

**Related:** [Capture of a capture of the original question](http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/)

Comment: See also: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7yfISlGLNU (explicit lyrics).

Comment: I really enjoyed that question...and I was sad to see it go.

Comment: Link to original question is dead, any other link?

Comment: @Koper: Matt McDole's capture is the only existing version that I know of (so if that's gone, it's *gone*). The original question was hard-deleted; not even 10k+ users can see it. It actually contained information that is against SO's privacy policy to release.

Comment: @MMyers: Like what?

Comment: @Arlen: Jeff posted the user's IP address to prove that it was a fake question.

Comment: @mmyers♦: Quoth the server: 404. (410 *Gone* would have been more dramatic, but OTOH it doesn't scan)

Comment: I'm still confused as to why they specifically chose the term _boat_ programming...

Comment: last obtainable archive capture: http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/

Comment: @mmyers why not hard delete _just_ Jeff's answer?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: A little late for that now, don't you think?

Comment: @mmyers yes, but I'm asking why we just didn't hard delete Jeff's answer? Why'd we have to hard delete the entire question?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: "We" had nothing to do with it. When this happened, the only moderators were the four employees of Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc.: Jeff, Joel, Jarrod, and Geoff. Jeff was the only one engaged in active moderation. (And for the record, I wasn't a moderator in May 2010.)

Comment: @mmyers that's still doesn't answer why the _entire_ question had to be deleted.

Comment: The "Background: See here" link points to a post that is closed as a duplicate of *this* question.

Comment: "Discussed on boat the podca.." *runs away*.

Answer (score 102):

**Meme:** Spam haiku

**Originator:**
Jeff Atwood likes fun
Played a trick on all of us
Now he must explain.

**First Heard:**
From [ennuikiller](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked)
First to find it; asks us all
[Jeff all so silent.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked/32546#32546)

**Cultural Height:**
haiku always vogue
And some also like to spam
Now bot must protect.

**Background:**
Others hit haiku
Questions begin to pile up
[Only talk: haiku.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32789/what-is-this-spam-haiku-nonsense-all-about)

Detection bot sees
Speaks in riddles of haiku
Makes us think again.

**Variants:**
Little slab of meat
In a wash of clear jelly
Now I heat the pan

[Cube of cold pinkness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32796/strange-haiki-after-posting-message-closed)
Yellow specks of porcine fat
Give me a spork please

**Fallout:**
many seek answers
many more post meta-kus
no more is knowing.

Comment: I think "ennuikiller" is 4 syllables: on-wee-kill-er

Comment: @gnostradamus Everybody's a critic.

Answer (score 100):

**Meme**: Friday Afternoon

**Origin**: [Olafur Waage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22459)

**Cultural Height**: Friday in Iceland

**Background**: Friday Afternoon is generally recognized as the period of the week when programmers like to slack off (more than usual) and begin an early unwinding from the past week's worth of not doing anything of great importance or productiveness. This time period would result in users posting "laid back" or "fun" questions on Stack Overflow, meeting both great acclaim and massive community outrage. (Note: such questions are no longer welcome there.)

The Friday Afternoon theme has now gained more traction on Meta Stack Exchange more than any other site in the League of Justice. It is not uncommon to see multiple "Friday Afternoon" questions posted throughout the day. This resulted in the creation of the tag [always-friday-in-iceland](/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland), which used to be quite popular until one sad day it got marked as a synonym of [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) and fun questions in general were curtailed.

There is no set time frame which Friday Afternoon falls, because as once said in a song, "It's 5 o'clock somewhere". Because of this, you are just as likely to see a question posted early on Friday morning (depending on your time zone) as you are to see one posted in the afternoon.

Comment: It's always Friday in Iceland apparently.

Comment: friday-afternoon tag seems gone

Comment: Because the people who maintain this site hate fun.

Comment: [The official "hates fun" post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Answer (score 88):

**Meme:** Everything is a meme

**Originator:** [TheTXI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

**Cultural Height:** [2009-09-10 16:41:20Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21221#21221)

**Background:** This meme began with TheTXI's obsession over memes in general, starting memes on Stack Overflow, and claiming memes for himself. In an effort to garner wide-spread adoption of his various bad habits and nervous tics, he began this project to catalog the prevailing memes on Meta Stack Overflow, making most of them up as he went along based on things that someone wrote, somewhere, a few times. It caught on. Sort of.

Comment: This meme entry is a meme. Divide by Zero. Oh shiiiii!

Comment: Why are TheTXI's ticks nervous? And why would I want to adopt one of them? Don't they already have homes? Or is that why they're nervous?

Comment: TheTXI has been known to crush pets. The ticks are *justifiably* nervous!

Comment: This video I think explains it all... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRHzQYmLuXk

Comment: I think you mean 'tics'.

Comment: Milhouse is not a meme!

Answer (score 88):

**Meme**: The Tim Stone Bat Signal

[image: Tim Stone Signal]

**Originator**: [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/921131#921131)

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: User [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone) is well known for his in-depth knowledge of the system and his ability to find/answer [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions. After [the Trogdor the Burninator request image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121577/131541) was created, a "Summon Tim Stone" image was created to summon Tim to investigate a bug report.

**Usage**: Comment / add to the end of a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) answer the image: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjhhD.png`. Also works in MSO chat, apparently.

Comment: Tim Stone signal for the win!

Answer (score 85):

**Meme**: Puns in the titles of tag-related requests

**Originator**: Unknown

**Cultural Height**: 2015

**Background**: With first appearances in 2013 ([All the [movement] has ceased](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260218/burn-the-movement)
| [Hack at the hacking tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251953/hack-at-the-hacking-tag)), it has become customary that burnination requests have catchy titles that pun on the name of the tag. Highlights (by vote count) include:

- [I want to delete the [internet]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255169/i-want-to-delete-the-internet)
- [Stop the [manipulation]!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298124/stop-the-manipulation)
- [The [hdd] tag is in the process of being cleaned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286177/umount-the-hdd)
- [Stop protecting [protect]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302679/stop-protecting-protect)
- [There is no [value] left in this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294230/this-tag-has-no-value)
- [Let's clean up [friendship]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308792/unfriend-friendship)
- [A [logical] discussion finally ends](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284906/what-isnt-logical)
- [rm -rf [.bash-script]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309222/rm-rf-bash-script)
- [Assert [assert] == [assertion] == [assertions]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288867/assert-assert-assertion-assertions)
- [The [player] is dead and can't respawn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284647/kill-the-player)
- [I think [override] [overrides] [method-overriding], [function-overriding], and even [overriding] itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306828/i-think-override-overrides-method-overriding-function-overriding-and-e)
- [An [exhaustive] list of reasons why this tag is superfluous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311809/an-exhaustive-list-of-reasons-why-this-tag-is-superfluous)
- [I declare [declarations] be a synonym of [declaration]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295205/i-declare-declarations-be-a-synonym-of-declaration)
- [Anyone up for [modified] questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262699/anyone-up-for-modified-questions)
- [This tag should not be [legal]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal)
- [​[game] over. Insert coin to burninate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294089/game-over-insert-coin-to-burninate)
- [compress [compression] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288599/compress-compression-tags)
- [Close the [art] gallery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295520/close-the-art-gallery)
- [Let [shellscript] burn in [shell]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292023/let-shellscript-burn-in-shell)
- [Can we comment out [code-comments] about [commenting] on [comments]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396940/can-we-comment-out-code-comments-about-commenting-on-comments)
- [Suggest [rounding] [number-rounding] to the nearest tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354866/suggest-rounding-number-rounding-to-the-nearest-tag).

Some of these even have been edited on purpose after having initially been posted with a boring standard "Burninate XY" title. For the why, see [Why do people have a little [pun] with their retag and burninate requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295583/1048572)

**Related**: [Trogdor the Burninator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/183280)

Comment: Here is [one of the better ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416466/) (MSO).

Answer (score 82):

**Meme:** Move the turtle in LOGO

**Originator:** Joel Spolsky

**Cultural Height:** June 16, 2009.

**Background:** During [Podcast 58](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/), Joel Spolsky experimented with the SO-Community by seeing how the community would respond to the question "[How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)"

**Further Background**: LOGO itself has now been used as a quasi-popular choice for users who assign a random programming language to a question that is asking how to do something but not providing enough background material (such as what language they are attempting to use).

Comment: "How do I iterate over a recordset" [in VB?] was another early $QUESTION.  If I recall correctly we'll know Stackoverflow has arrived when S.O. becomes the first Google hit on this question.
Probably not worthy of "meme", though.

Comment: @gbarry: Rigth now, http://stackoverflow.com appears consistently fourth in different querys for that question.

Comment: Now it's first.

Comment: Any mirrors, caches or screens for this? I'd love to see this thread, but it's *removed* right now! :(

Comment: @Cawas I was able to find it on the Wayback: http://web.archive.org/web/20101030214847/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan! Unfortunately we can't participate on that one, but it's better than nothing. [Here I just made yet another backup, as an image](http://i.imgur.com/Mwbcz.jpg).

Answer (score 77):

**Meme**: Hyphen site

**Originator**: Unknown

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: [Jeff Atwood created a blog-post defining Stack Overflow as the anti-Experts-Exchange.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html) experts-exchange.com was originally just expertsexchange.com. The change (to avoid the domain being mistaken for ExpertSexChange.com) occurred years prior to Jeff's blog, but the legacy of the site lent to this nickname on Meta Stack Overflow.

Often seen as "you know, that *other* question-and-answer site. With the hyphen in the name... *you* know what I'm talking about" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 74):

**Meme**: Community Wiki Police

**Aliases**: Watchful, Community-minded Users

**Originator**: [Lance Roberts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11745#11745)

**Cultural Height**: 10th October, 2010 - [the day Community Wiki questions went the way of the dodos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183)

**Definition**: To [demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141998), via [downvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216876) or [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205893), [t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124968)[h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067084)[a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040338)[t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108008) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970190) [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205191)[u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870757)[e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146014)[s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188551)[t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149778)[i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961942)[o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876344)[n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171321) be made [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324).

Comment: that is a question are now all separate links

Comment: 17 links in 1 line of text. That has to be some sort of record.

Comment: @rcartaino - And I'm sure they're the tip of the iceberg

Comment: @rcartaino: Ha, I've got that beat.  Behold my 19 links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10114/search-for-windows-7-does-not-parse-as-expected/10117#10117

Comment: Its interesting that some of my comments, particularly related to downvoting, was lumped in with the community wiki police when I've been posting pretty consistently for the last 9 months that CW is a bad feature. See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639035/the-perfect-programming-language) for context: one user voted to close a "fun" thread unless wiki'd, which I feel amounts to bullying. So I singled out one his own non-wiki'd "fun" threads as a demonstration that CW policing is inconsistent in a "taste of your own medicine" kind of way.

Comment: @Juliet: Your trolling has been duly noted and reported.

Comment: @kev: Right. We have been over this. I can point to your blog comments if you would like to cast stones. Try and get over your crush on me please, for the community's sake.

Comment: See [When to mark the ‘community wiki’ checkbox on a new question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888)

Comment: This CW police should no longer be possible under the new rules - maybe Cultural Height can be determined now.

Comment: I like the 'fade select' effect on 'that a question'. Oh wait...

Comment: @RobertCartaino It is a record no longer. http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1317/56 has beaten the record with 74 links in 1 line of text.

Answer (score 71):

**Meme:**  Meta effect.

**Originator:**  [Mat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158667/mat) (?)

**Mentioned:**  [MSO comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105579/is-the-populist-badge-motivating-the-wrong-behavior#comment270808_105579), 2011-09-08

**Background:** Increase of voting activities observed on main-site posts that have been exposed at meta. Most ironic when someone complaining to Meta about "unfair downvotes" on another site gets more downvotes. Also seen: closing, re-opening, deleting, etc. Often the opposite of the desired result for the user who came to Meta about the specific question.

**Cultural height:** Low ([seen infrequently in MSO comments](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22meta+effect%22+site:meta.stackexchange.com)).

Comment: The cultural effect may be low but the, well, vote effect - not that low at all :-(

Comment: I feel like this is getting more and more prevalent with time

Answer (score 69):

**Meme:** Changing your display name on a whim.

**Originator:** [Welbog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/52443/welbog)

**Cultural Height:** TBD

**Official Response:** [Limited to one change every 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180).

**Background:** User [Welbog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/52443/welbog) likes to change his profile whenever it will make a post of his seem funnier. Other times it seems to just be on a whim. He will also edit his "About Me" text, to fit in with his current display name.

- [Welbog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/52443/welbog)
- Welboug (Old English spelling)
- [Welbo_g](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainfck-offensive) (Censored Old English spelling)
- Ouèlbogue (French spelling)
- Susan (From the "new name for Welbog" contest)
- Susan Papadismgaogenabhieanae
- [Susan Papadismgaogenabhieanaelaegkae](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/how-is-the-tagging-system-implemented-here-at-sofu)
- [www.biglaser.net](http://www.biglaser.net) (He is a big fan of lasers) <sup><sub>[(referenced here)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26224/people-never-down-vote)</sub></sup>
- [Steven Spielberg's Welbog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26437/Welbog-the-Movie/26440#26440) (Waste of a movie)
- [Robox Prime](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27046/with-more-awesome-in-your-face/27050#27050) (best cartoon on television in 2009)
- Chicago Ted
- I'm really awesome. Really.
- [welbog at googlewave.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28703/how-is-the-sea-perfume)
- [Hellbog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/playful-parodies-possibly-pose-plenty-perplexing-problems/) (Evil twin of Smellbog)
- Birthday Welbog
- firtjer (It's [fretje's fault](http://welbog.homeip.net/%7Einferno/images/so/firtjer.png))
- Gargamel ([because they only had on Smurfette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31168/fork-you-frell-you-and-frakk-you/31196#31196))
- NIfE
- [The Encapsulator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48974/cyber-bullies-stole-my-identity-lunch-money)
- [The Proposer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52900/area51-silliness-what-does-it-mean/52925#52925)
- Weblog
- Double Welbog
- Toronto
- [Sid Meier](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/245108#245108)
- Whom
- Killbog
- FYI I'm still changing my name
- Can't stop the photons
- A very laser Christmas
- JSONBog

Also independently started by [voyager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130127/voyager) in response to a [post asking what constituted spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/what-constitutes-spam/21824#21824), trying to convey that some users *are* spam, comedic effect enhanced by answering [in a post complaining about the Amazon Monty Python ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21855/monty-python-book-ad-showing-up-in-python-questions/21864#21864) appearing when first introduced. After that, it just degenerated into a neverending competition with welbog to out do the wackiness of the other user's changes.

- voyager
- [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21855/monty-python-book-ad-showing-up-in-python-questions/21864#21864)
- [Eggs, Spam, Ham and Spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22433/possible-bug-with-ads)
- Arthur voyager King <!-- had forgotten about this one! -->
- [smeagol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23724/small-formatting-quirk-that-bothers-me/23725#23725)
- [spam AKA smeagol AKA voyager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/i-think-i-was-just-serial-downvoted-how-can-this-prevented-by-the-community/23008#23008)
- ûöyàgúer (or something like that)
- [`viyager`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25676/do-vba-questions-belong-on-so-or-su/25682#25682)
- voyager's back
- voyager's mask
- the man with the shifting name
- voyλger
- waveyλger ([Google Wave is a time sink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28882/what-is-your-google-wave-id))
- [json](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44461/usernames-ending-in-json-cause-trouble/44465#44465)
- perbert

#### Other changes of management

Several other users have subsequently engaged in this meme.  See the [edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/26518/revisions) if you want to see all the individual participants and their name changes.  Meme listings are not complete catalogues.

Comment: But never "V'ger"? :(

Answer (score 69):

**Meme**: Porblem, Proble, Halting Issue, Pro-blem, pr0blem, proble*

**Originator**: [Kevin Montrose](/users/130213)

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: Late 2011, the SO devs decided to add a filter to question titles blocking (among others) the word `Problem`. Even though this change undoubtedly managed to block a lot of crap (if just for a short time), it lead to great discontent among the Meta community. With great glee, they pointed out that people started circumventing the filter by deliberately misspelling the word or inserting punctuations - among them `proble`,  `pro-blem`, and `proble*`. Various users and moderators have renamed themselves in protest:

- Josh Caswell: `Problem`
- MPelletier: `problAm`
- NullUserException ♦: `ProblematicTitleException ♦`
- Robert Harvey ♦: `pr0blem ♦`

**Related**:

- [Remove blacklist filter for `problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem)
- [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)
- [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles)
- [Moderators should be immune to the word filters in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115007/moderators-should-be-immune-to-the-word-filters-in-titles)
- [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-the-worst-idea-ever-implemented-on-so)
- [The Efficacy Of Stack Overflow's Question Title Filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter)

Comment: Originator: Kevin Montrose, of course.

Comment: Another case, this time on Super User: [p-r-o-b-l-e-m](http://superuser.com/revisions/393950/1). (LOL!)

Comment: Not to mention replacing some letters with similar looking unicode variants (eg o with the greek omicron).

Answer (score 66):

**Meme**: Greasemonkey

**Originator**: [Jonathan Sampson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson)

**Cultural Height**: First month of Meta Stack Overflow's existence.

**Background**: Greasemonkey originated as an offshoot of the Stack Overflow jQuery meme. This is due to the high frequency of requests by users for certain types of functionality for the Stack Overflow family of websites, many of which were easily solved using custom Greasemonkey scripts. Before long nearly every feature request could be seen as solvable through some type of Greasemonkey script (whether for real or just in the imagination of a commenter).

**See Also**: [jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/173052) (Stack Overflow predecessor)

Comment: Use Greasemonkey!

Comment: Disagree. Use Tampermonkey :)

Comment: Disagree; Use Violentmonkey.

Comment: It doesn't matter, get a monkey of your choice to do the job

Answer (score 63):

**Meme:** The Language That Must Not Be Named (or Brainf_ck)

**Originator:** Unclear. The censorship of the Language That Must Not Be Named has been around for a long time. However, the question that caused the ensuing war was asked by user [Jon B](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/27414/jon-b) in response to the [favorite esoteric language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187715/what-is-your-favorite-esoteric-programming-language) question on Stack Overflow, where several people (notably [Lance Roberts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13295/lance-roberts), [myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135301/chris-lutz), and, appropriately, He Who Must Not Be Named) were engaged in a low-intensity edit war.

**Cultural Height:** TBD

**Background:** [The little question that started the big war](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainfck-offensive) was asked by Jon B after a certain more liberal (on this issue, at least - I can't speak for his personal or political beliefs) [moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) asked that the term be preserved, as it is the name of the language. Several users replied, generating much heated debate and some equally heated flaming. The conflict lasted for several hours, generating 13 upvotes on two answers in favor of the term being used unaltered, 9 in favor of it being used but resigned that it probably shouldn't be, and several others, along with a notable (and rather noble) answer by Lance out-and-out opposed to the word that generated an impressive -19 votes. Then Jeff Atwood came in, edited (and locked) all posts to use the censored form, and effectively ended the debate.

**Further Background:** It should be noted that the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainfck-offensive/24085#24085), while a good answer (it received an upvote from me), is not representative of the highest "community-choice" answer (and isn't meant to be - Jon B said he picked the answer he most agreed with, since there really doesn't seem to be an answer *everyone* can agree on in this situation).

Answer (score 59):

**Meme:** Slowest Cheater in the East (SCITE)

**Originator:** Mehrdad

**First Heard:** August 26th, 2009

**Definition:** A term borne of the protest incited when changes to the default sorting order of questions were instituted to compensate for the [disproportionate attention given late-arriving answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533).

**Background**: On August 26th, questions with the same vote rank were changed from a sort order of oldest-first to a random ordering. This change sparked a controversy among users who claimed that the change would encourage "strategic down-voting."

From: [What has happened to the sorting of answers on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17624/what-has-happened-to-the-sorting-of-answers-on-stack-overflow/17772#17772)

> The new system creates plenty of
>   horrible problems (the slowest cheater
>   in the east (SCITE) problem) just to
>   solve FGITW, which was not a big
>   issue.
>
> For instance, today, I answered a
>   question and a virtually identical
>   answer appeared 3 minutes later and
>   got upvoted. In this specific case,
>   the guy himself was nice enough to
>   upvote me, but I honestly don't think
>   it's a good thing to post a dupe
>   answer after 3 minutes and leave it
>   there. -- Mehrdad

Comment: This is not a meme, it is an acronym.

Comment: A meme is a catchphrase or concept. "Slowest Cheater in the East" qualifies on both accounts (which just happens to have a convenient acronym).

Comment: Or, by some personal preferences, it could be an initia... I just had the strangest sense of déjà vu.

Comment: So, should you have downvoted the dup?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody pointed out the fact that the acronym coincides with the name of the SciTE text editor.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: Clearly the only thing to do is to fork SciTE and call the new branch FGitW....

Comment: [FGitW reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533).

Comment: [SciTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE) reference.

Answer (score 59):

**Meme**: Too Many Shogs

**Originator**: [JAL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/242209/jal)

**First Heard:** [A bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289395/242209) posted by JAL where when Shog closed a question as multiple duplicates, the iOS Stack Exchange App would show that the question was closed by multiple Shogs.

**Status**: [no longer reproducible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9). Now we have [Too Few Shogs.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stackexchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with-t)

> [image: Close bug]

**Cultural Height**: Shortly after the bug report was opened.

**Background**: Due to shortcomings with the Stack Exchange API, a question cannot be closed as multiple duplicates.  Shog voted to close a question three times using one account, carefully triggering a server error half-way through the processing of the first two votes so as to add multiple duplicate links.  This gave the appearance that multiple Shogs closed the question.  Thus, jokes about too many Shogs, what happened to Shogs 1-8, and Shog's Socks were shared on Meta and on Chat.  The bug has since been fixed and we will miss all of the Shogs.

Comment: HTTP 509 (Too many shogs)

Answer (score 55):

**Meme**: **HE WHO SHALL NOT BE NAMED**

**Originator**: [TheTXI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22164/thetxi)

**Cultural Height**: Early July 2009

**Background**: **HE WHO SHALL NOT BE NAMED** is [Rich B](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/5640/rich-b). The oldest surviving reference is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3857/name-reason-for-stackoverflow/3862#3862), earlier references having been on questions since deleted.  There are [urban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3383/comments) [legends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3456/comments) surrounding him, all of which are probably true.

**Another Alias**: [Geoffrey Chetwood, now GEOCHET](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/5640/geochet)

Answer (score 51):

**Meme:** Getting Shogged

**Origin:** Unknown (possibly the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=shogged&room=89))

**Cultural Height:** unfortunately, [somewhere in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9)

**Usage:** whenever somebody, having posted an (often unfounded) complaint about Stack Exchange, gets corrected by either a convincing data-analysis or a rhetoric masterpiece by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), that person is said to have been [shogged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shog).

Comment: Please don't vent your frustrations by vandalizing this entry. If the phenomenon you are referring to has become a meme in itself, a new answer/entry would be appropriate.

Comment: @Robert it's not vandalizing, the editor who put the change is the one who added this meme

Comment: It was a thinly veiled attempt at expressing my frustration; I intended to revert it to the original spelling on a date to be determined. Even if I wasn't the author of this answer, is it such a bad joke? This Q&A *is* tagged [tag:fun] after all ...

Comment: I vote for keeping it fun then, and not bringing in the drama. I understand it's yours and the frustration (I probably share at least part of it...)... But this isn't the kind of 'fun' we should have, I think... It reminds me of the kind of 'fun' schoolkids have when bullying others by changing their name to mean something mean.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard if this was an ordinary answer, that would make some sense, but this is Community Wiki. The nature of Community Wiki is that no one truly "owns" the answer. The one who created it is simply the first contributor.

Answer (score 49):

**Meme:** Oscillation

**Originator:** [asdf_enel_hak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168587/asdf-enel-hak)

**First Heard:** [February 3rd, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166048/new-phenomenon-rage-unaccepting/166098#166098) (Deleted. >10k only. [Screenshot for mortals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3B5W.png))

**Cultural Height:** Oscillates between then and now

**Definition:** The repetitive variation, typically in time, of some measure about a central value (often a point of equilibrium) or between two or more different states ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation)). Familiar examples include a swinging pendulum, AC power, and a fickle mind.

**Background:** A user experienced an existential crisis and, as a result of "a changing mind", started to "think larger", "in any direction". This led them on an [answer-unaccepting spree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166048/new-phenomenon-rage-unaccepting), subverting (or, in their own words, *oscillating*) the accept system by taking away the well-deserved 15 reputation from every user who had hitherto answered their questions to their satisfaction, as well as the 2 reputation that was originally awarded to themself for accepting the answers to begin with.

Comment: It still brings tears to my eyes when I recall I was there for the creation. No, really.

Comment: Personally I prefer [this form of oscillation](http://jsfiddle.net/EPutG/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: This has bled over IRL for me; I've started using this as my answer at home as well. "Why aren't the dishes done?" "Oscillation."

Comment: The original answer has been deleted. Screenshot [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/624DM.png).

Comment: Hmm, didn't realize I was voting to delete a meme. I thought it was just incomprehensible nonsense. Like [Time Cube](http://www.timecube.com/).

Comment: @Cody Gray: To be fair, that's precisely what made it a meme (which I didn't invent, only documented here).

Comment: Noooo, the answer got deleted?! That answer was amazing! :P But seriously, it's linked to all over the place; I'm going to have to get 10k on meta *just* to vote to undelete it :( (@Cody)

Comment: Deleted by a moderator, @Doorknob. 10k won't help there.

Comment: @Arjan [Noooooooo](http://nooooooooooooooo.com)

Answer (score 48):

**Meme:** "The Great Mythical Rep Re-Calc"

**Originator:** ???

**First Heard:** (by me? [two minutes ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28469/what-will-happen-after-the-great-reputation-re-calc-closed).  but [I'm really awesome. Really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/52443/im-really-awesome-really) sez so, so it's gotta be true, right?)

**Cultural Height:** 5'3" without shoes.  Or so I've heard.

**Background:** Apparent fears of [downvote weights increasing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased) among the general user population.  [Rep-whores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522) in fear for their ill-gotten points.  Due to arrive in [six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514), although it's possible my [leg is being pulled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21224#21224).

**Official Response:** The Great Mythical Rep Re-Calc [occurred in March, 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010).  Rumors now grow of another Great Rep Re-Calc.  It could occur in as little as [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)...

<strike>[More research is needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19480#19480).</strike>

[The other shoe dropped Feb 27, 2011.  Nothing will ever be the same.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-reputation-drop-problem-points-disappeared-and-score-lost-recalc)

[The final shoe dropped almost exactly a year later. Everything will always be the same (where "everything" encompasses only "display rep" and "actual rep").](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)

Comment: You mean the great *mythical* rep recalc. :) Like unicorns, we don't know that it actually exists in anything but our wildest fantasies. It's promised to arrive "in six to eight weeks".

Comment: thx, fixed.  and blamed, for what it's worth.  :)

Comment: as long as it handles hanging chads

Comment: "Cultural Height: 5'3" without shoes." - You don't wear shoes in public?

Comment: that was added by someone not me.  plus, i'm taller than that.  but yeah, it so happens that i'm frequently shoeless in public.  season and location dependant, of course.

Answer (score 47):

**Meme**: Caching (“caching, it's always caching”)

**Originator**: [Jonathan Sampson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson) ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/922/223030))

**Cultural height**: just now

**Background**: Many "[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s" turn out to be a caching issue (client-side, or server-side, or in between) resolving itself later due to a cache refresh. Currently there are [over 1150 comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/168054/caching-comments) on Meta mentioning caching.

[Taken to new heights while troubleshooting OAuth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224636/223030):

> Too bad I couldn't clear the cache on my high school dancing... probably why my senior prom silently failed. Never saw my date or my wallet again.

**Derived meme**: [“localization, it's always localization”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193268/why-is-the-review-suggested-edits-dialog-box-missing-its-title#comment605001_193268), which appeared during the preparation work for [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese). And [sometimes it's localization caching!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211166/223030)

**See also:** http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: I cannot believe this was never here until now.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Are you sure you weren't looking at a cached version? ;)

Comment: @juergen why the rollback? Care to explain what was wrong in the edit?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I just liked my revision more.

Comment: 29391 posts on main-SO about it.

Comment: Related, but external: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com just displays "Yes. Advice may be invalid due to caching.". How is this relevant? Does it add anything worthwhile?

Comment: @PeterMortensen that site is typically linked to on posts reporting "bugs" that are really just cached variables not updating.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Several years after the fact and a minor aside, but I created that site in large part due to caching-related bug answers here

Answer (score 45):

**Meme:** Tim Post lost his keys

**Originator:** [Tim Post](/users/50049/tim-post)

**Cultural Height:** TBD

**Background:** In [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/152859) to [Should 'drive by' downvoting be more effectively caught?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215379/33577), Tim Post describes a long chain of events, starting with him losing his keys, to explain why an answer was downvoted. Since then, "Tim Post lost his keys again" has become a somewhat frequent explanation for random and inexplicable events.

Comment: According to another Tim post, this kind of thing is not an isolated incident: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144601/reversing-a-year-long-ban-on-meta-stack-overflow/144680#144680

Answer (score 42):

**Meme**: Link or it didn't happen

**Origin**: Paraphrase of [Pics or it didn't happen](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pics-or-it-didnt-happen)

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: Used in response to a user claiming an event (usually offensive to that user) inside S[OFU] or meta, without actually providing a link to the question or answer for the rest to see it really happened, or to judge if it was just a misunderstanding.

See [Example question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40427) (as of this writing, there is no link to proof of the claims, but you may need to see the edit history to see the first, original revision)

Answer (score 41):

**Meme**: Oy

**Origin**: [rchern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140548/rchern)

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**First Seen**: MSO Chat, probably in The Tavern

**Background**: Not completely known. Some believe it is the Jewish / Yiddish phrase "Oy Vey". Others like Michael Myers believe "It's 'yo' backwards. [Because] everything is backwards in Missouri.". "Oy" most frequently shows up in MSO chat, with at least 2 - 5 "oy"s showing up per day

[image]

Also, roughly 85% of the time "oy" is said in chat, that message receives at least one if not multiple stars. Some like Yi Jiang believe "oy"s are a form of currency.

Comment: "oy" could refer to representation of Russian word "оу"(cyrillic) which means "Oh" in English. And considering that surname Chernoff (the surname of user rchern) has Russian roots it could be right explanation of oy's nature .

Comment: @igormilla oy, it's obviously currency.

Comment: Might also be related to [Oi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oi_(interjection))?

Comment: In Brazilian Portuguese it's "[hello](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oi_(interjei%C3%A7%C3%A3o))".

Answer (score 40):

**Meme:** We Hate Fun

**Originator:** Jeff Atwood, https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

**Mentioned:** Wherever fun is being had.

**Background:** This meme may have started before the blog post concerning fun questions on Stack Overflow, but since the blog post it has seemingly grown to cover the suppression of fun in general.

**Common usage:**

> Comment: Hey why is my post being downvoted? Don't you people have a sense of
>   humor?
>
> Response: We hate fun.

**Cultural height:** unsure.

Comment: "We hate fun." Posted on a meme thread. Riiiiiiight.

Comment: @MD XF meta is different

Answer (score 35):

**Meme:** bring back the polyglot

**Originators:** [gparyani](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/), [the4kman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3151675/the4kman)

**Background:** It started when the Stack Overflow 404 page was [changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363148/5861618) to no longer include the [polyglot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/). gparyani asked [Bring back the 404 polyglot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363224) on Meta Stack Overflow, and then [the4kman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3151675/the4kman) [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363273/5861618) saying he changed his profile picture to this:

[image: avatar]

And everyone was free to join him. Many users have been using the picture in their profiles. [Some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4284627/) even in creative ways:

[image: Donald Duck avatar]

When asked for an explanation of the languages used in this "new polyglot", [the4kman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3151675/the4kman) responded:

> It uses 326 different languages and throws a compiler error in each one of them.

Comment: Cultural height: 404

Answer (score 34):

**Meme:** Always Friday in Iceland

**Originator:** [Ólafur Waage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22459/olafur-waage) (?)

**Cultural Height:** TBD

**Background:** While programmers enjoy [Friday Afternoons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413) they've also been known to do things other than work during the week. So [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) created the [always-friday-in-iceland](/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland) tag, because we all know [those Icelanders are always making jokes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30134/has-tony-the-pony-been-hacked-closed).

Comment: Cf. [Friday afternoon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413)

Comment: While our viking friend might be why the term came to existence, I believe it was [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) who [created the badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54668/retag-request-friday-afternoon-always-friday-in-iceland).

Comment: @MatrixFrog Please do not abuse the `<kbd>` tag - kbd abuse, as Meta users should well know, is punishable by castle banishment.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be used for tags as well as keyboard shortcuts. My apologies.

Comment: What, you guys don't have an `always-friday-in-iceland` key on your keyboards?

Answer (score 34):

**Meme**: Calvin and Hobbes-rolling

**Originator**: [Pekka](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/pekka), Collaborator: [Tim Manishearth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134707/102937)

**Cultural Height**:

[image]

**Background**: In an effort to make it more fun for users who try and get around the question-asking ban on Stack Overflow by asking their wildly off-topic questions on Meta, it's now possible to get a customized "Calvin and Hobbes" answer, free of charge.

It aims to replace the "we get a hundred off-topic programming posts a day AAARGH!" complaint of MSO users with "Sweet! A hundred comic strips a day!"

There's now [a script](https://stackapps.com/q/3477/10098) that aids C&H-rollers in their nefarious deeds.

Comment: Special bonus: lengthy suspensions for the hapless question-askers.

Comment: you suspend 'em? Should I flag those instead of just VtCing as off topic?

Comment: @BenBrocka: They get dealt with pretty quickly.  But yes, you can flag.

Comment: On a serious note: doesn't this somehow tell oblivious folks that it's okay to post unrelated "answers"?

Comment: @arj - I partially agree with you there.  Although these kinds of posts get downvoted off the home page pretty fast, closed almost immediately and shortly after deleted so there is not much risk of advertising "bad" behavior.  [Adding minimal information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135358/172936) to the post itself would perhaps minimize the "unrelated answer" issue too...

Comment: Of course, with the description above all is clear, @Robert. But when posted as *"This is an interesting question, to which I don't know the answer, but I have this comic"* things might not be that clear at all, I feel. Keep in mind the OP didn't even understand they were posting off topic to start with. I'm afraid they won't see the sarcasm in such response either. (But then indeed: I also don't know if that makes things worse.)

Comment: @Arjan: I'd guess the 2/3 of all misguided posters are question banned on SO and will stop collaborating anyway (if it can be called that). The other 1/3 just missed the "Ask Question" button, landed on Meta, failed to recognize the different theme, did not notice the obscure must-have-tags which no other question on SO has and completely ignored any other hint that they are wrong...possibility that those become 'valuable' collaborators is...well...not so hot either. ... But you can show me examples to proof me wrong, please!

Comment: @Arjan: I've gotten one response from a cartoon.  It was: "Ah, yeah, you're right, posted in the wrong place.  Sorry about that."   Most of these folks are question-banned on SO; they know very well what they are doing.  They want us to migrate their off-topic question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are users really allowed to post off-topic answers like that? I haven't seen anyone do it. Is that because the rules have changed since this answer was posted or just because they've stopped doing it for another reason?

Comment: @DonaldDuck: It hasn't happened in awhile; the last time was probably shortly after I posted the last comment five years ago.  Ah, good times.

Answer (score 32):

**Meme:**  name change to "Tim *something*".

**Originator:**  [Tim Post](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=961968#961968) (?)

**Mentioned:**  Tavern, May 14 2012

**Background:**  Extraordinary ping-ability of the name @Tim.

- ["Tim" Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone)
- ["Tim" ManishEarth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178438/tim-manishearth)
- ["Tim" jadarnel27](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168428/tim-jadarnel27)
- ["Tim" Site is a Forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/134300/tim-site-is-a-forum)
- ["Tim" Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150097/tim-yi-jiang)
- ["Timootinator"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/966583#966583) <sup>see note on usage specifics below</sup>
- ["Tim" Rob Hruska](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=962007#962007)

> Three Tims for the Elven-devs in the Tavern,
> Seven for the Moderation-overlords in their halls of 01100010011010010111010001110011,
> Nine for New Users doomed to downvotes,
> One for the Jeff Atwood on his dark throne
> In the Land of Horror where the Coding lies.
> One Tim to rule them all, One Tim to find them,
> One Tim to bring them all and in the darkness bind them
> In the Land of Horror where the Coders lie.

> - [Anonymous](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1687351#1687351)

**Cultural height:**  TBD.

**Usage specifics:**  Put a space after Tim in order to get notifications when pinged @Tim.

Comment: I'd say the originator was [Tim Post](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=961968#961968).

Comment: I am unfortunately to blame for that. Not my finest idea by any stretch.

Comment: Like this? Tim Burr!

Answer (score 29):

**Meme**: GIF of fox jumping in the snow

**Originator**: [TGMCians](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/244382/tgmcians), in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2641618#2641618)

**Cultural height**: TBD

**Background**: TGMCians posted the animated GIF of the fox jumping in the snow in chat, and later, the image was posted several times and some people even added it to the "about me" on their profile. The fox GIF looks like this:

[image: Fox GIF]

[The fox is actually catching a mouse buried beneath the snow](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/north-america/animals/red-fox.htm).

Comment: http://pyrrha.csisdmz.ul.ie/4012/animated-gifs/IWQNcGes9u.gif

Comment: [This video was posted as answer on MSO too.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276686/2982225)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 28):

**Meme:** A Stack Overflow Carol

**Originator:** [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tiny-tim)

**Cultural Height:** Christmas

**About:** One day near Christmas 2011, [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tiny-tim) decided to change his name to Tiny Tim, a character from Charles Dickens's *[A Christmas Carol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol)*.  That prompted other users to change their names to other characters from the story, including...

- [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/59303/scrooge) - Scrooge
- [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/mrs-cratchit) - Mrs. Cratchit
- [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/145982/fezziwig) - Fezziwig
- [John](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152101/bob-cratchit) - Bob Cratchit
- [casperOne](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140951/the-ghost-of-christmas-past) - The Ghost of Christmas Past
- [mmyers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13531/the-ghost-of-christmas-present) - The Ghost of Christmas Present
- [Ninefingers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/142852/the-ghost-of-xmas-yet-to-come) - The Ghost of Xmas yet to come
- [Roryalsop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/154443/jacob-marley) - Jacob Marley
- [Powerlord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15880/jacob-marley) - another Jacob Marley
- [tombull89](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155320/tiny-tom) - another Tiny Tim (Tom, in this case)
- [mootinator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/153001/tiny-mootim) - yet another Tiny Tim (Tiny mooTim)

And one character from a different Christmas story:

- [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/102937/grinch) - Grinch

And yet another character from yet another Christmas story:

- [studiohack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/144987/rudolph-the-red-nosed-reindeer) - Rudolph the Red Nosed Reindeer

And from other holiday related things:

- [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/nine-shogs-shogging) - Nine Shogs Shogging
- [Kev](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/419/the-antisanta) - The AntiSanta
- [Pubby](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/169859/santa-claus) - Santa Claus

This occured again near Christmas, 2012 where the Stack Exchange moderators invited all to [join in actual meta-carols](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158615/the-moderators-have-decided-to-have-a-little-yuletide-fun-join-us-will-you), and again in 2013 as well as 2014.

Answer (score 23):

**Meme:** [Paddington Bear Choppertars](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1850/32986)

**Originator:** http://meta.serverfault.com/users/1435/chopper3

**Cultural Height:** SF regulars are pretty ADD - Most of us switched back to normal avatars about a week after that meta question was asked.

**Background:** See [Paddington Bear Choppertar](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1850/32986), it's all explained.

**Seriously, how is this a Meta meme?** Maybe it is, maybe it isn't, but it garnered some attention and lots of chat discussions for the week or so we had it going on.  Also it's got Paddington Freakin' Bear so you know it's cool!

Answer (score 21):

**Meme:** Bart

**Originator:** [Bart](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/161198/bart), in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bart&Room=89&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=stars)

**Cultural Height:** The usage of the iconic glasses as profile images by multiple users.
[image]

**Background:** Bart, his glasses, his smiting stick and his stars are legendary in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), as evident from the topic of the room "*MY GOD, IT'S FULL OF STARS!*"

**Usage:** If Bart posts a message, ★ it!

Comment: and no description about goggles ?

Comment: Glasses @TGMCians. Glasses ...

Comment: Ahhh @Bart Yes..

Comment: Wonder what took us so long to acknowledge Bart's memesness.

Comment: It could only be done by a nemesis @ShadowWizard.

Comment: a memesis? *facepalms himself*

Comment: "Usage: If Bart posts a message, ★ it!" - Thats a misuse of Bart.

Comment: We misuse him all the time @nicael.

Comment: Your popularity increased @Bart, finally got [a badge for your meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=245167) :)

Comment: Yay @InfiniteRecursion. Well deserved.

Answer (score 20):

**Meme:** Thanks in Advantage

**Originator:** Stack Overflow

**Cultural Height:** Unknown

**Background:** On Stack Overflow it had become somewhat common for a new user to place 'Thanks in advantage' in their questions in order to thank any users who answered. Besides this terrible spelling mistake, 'thanks' in posts is not allowed and as of March 2015 has been eradicated via [this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it?cb=1).

Answer (score 18):

**Meme:** "[Updating the Changing name Meme Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518)"

**Originator:** Brad Gilbert

**First Heard:** Answer posted at Oct 19 at 23:28. [First written acknowledgment of meme status was 2009-11-28](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/is-im-tired-of-seeing-this-get-bumped-a-valid-reason-to-lock-a-post).

**Cultural Height:** 2009-11-28, when it was crushed down by a locking.

**Background:** Answer to *The Many Memes of Meta* question, it had become custom to keep it updated whenever a user changed his/her/its name.

**Controversy:** Thanks to a big effort of the community, the answer was kept updated regularly, being edited sometimes [several times in a single day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/26518/list). This ongoing edition of that particular answer, kept bumping [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/) question to the front page, [something that started to bother some users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/is-im-tired-of-seeing-this-get-bumped-a-valid-reason-to-lock-a-post/31214#31214). In an attempt to stop the ongoing edition, moderator [Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/658/kyle-cronin) ♦ decided to lock the answer in question, [sparking some controversy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/is-im-tired-of-seeing-this-get-bumped-a-valid-reason-to-lock-a-post/31239#31239). Most moderators and half [users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/is-im-tired-of-seeing-this-get-bumped-a-valid-reason-to-lock-a-post/31212#31212), [including](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/is-im-tired-of-seeing-this-get-bumped-a-valid-reason-to-lock-a-post/31220#31220) [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) ♦, supported the decision at the time.

*To be updated daily for the next 30 days.*

Comment: If this is updated daily, I will pillage your village !!

Comment: Some legal advice: to sidestep the pillaging, update it hourly.

Comment: While I sort of initiated the controversy, I think intentionally replicating the problem on another post is really not going to help much ... In fact, I kinda think it'll hurt the cause.

Comment: @John Rudy: the last sentence was a joke, of course. @Ólafur Waage: I'll be waiting for you, you barbarian!

Comment: @waveyλger: Cool beans. :) (I think some people may take you seriously on it ... :) (Yes, I cheated & used copy-and-paste for your name.)

Answer (score 17):

**Meme**: The homepage is **being Yaakoved**

**Originator**: Shadow Wizard ([in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8621484#8621484))

**Cultural height**: 2021

**Background**: When launching a new feature that has been discussed for years. [Yaakov Ellis ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis) will mark these old questions with the appropriate status tag. The result is a homepage (i.e. the list of recently active questions) with loads of red-tagged questions.

[image: Screenshot of 11 posts edited by Yaakov within 22 minutes in one view.]

Comment: Why is “Wizards” a related meme? It’s about many users having a similar name, whereas this is about a staff member mass-tagging old feature requests. Is it because you see “modified […] ⟨Something⟩ Wizard” quite often on the homepage? Seems a bit far-fetched…

Comment: No, because the originator is a wizzard @user289905

Comment: Being posted under the title of "many memes", meme it maketh not.

Comment: Where has the word "Yaakoved" been used?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q in chat. See the link after **Originator**

Comment: @Mari funny word that was adopted by others can be seen as a meme.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard It's not a meme because someone turned a  person's name into an adjective, it's called English! Shakespearean, Dickensian, Trumpism, Augustan, Thatcherite etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA isn't it being used as a verb here?

Comment: Yes, used in the passive voice @YaakovEllis. Personally, I would have favoured *yaakovied* But "Yaakoved" could also be used an adjective e.g The Yaakoved main page.

Comment: @shadow  He is the Yaakovian of transformation, then?

Answer (score 16):

**Meme**: Continuous outbursts of excessive analogies and profane demonstrations

**Originator**: Welbog

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: The background on this meme started with his profile, which describes him to the core: https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog

**Example**: see below...

Comment: I'm going to come to your house and grate all of your cheese, increasing its surface area and promoting mould propagation! Ahaha! Your family will visit you for your famous cheese soufflé but will discover a green and blue soufflé instead of a more naturally coloured one such as yellow or orange! The rumours will spread about how unsanitarily you keep your living arrangements. People will think that you don't bathe and that your dog has fleas. And your cat has fleas! **And your pony has fleas!!** You will never live this down, and you'll be forced to move to east Virginia where no one looks.

Comment: But back to my main point: your grated cheese will still have more surface area than normal cheese, even though you spent several hours painstakingly braiding it. You remember that string cheese that used to be popular when we were kids? Does that still exist anymore? I hated that stuff, but it was neat so I still wanted it. Luckily my parents were smart and never bought it for me. That stuff is bound to be loaded with unnatural things like pony claws and dog fleas and stuff. Anyway, while you're in east Virginia can you pick me up a copy of the Alexandria Gazette Packet? I want one.

Comment: @Welbog I love dachshunds! My wife and I have 2.

Comment: Welbog always delivers.

Comment: De-livers? Sounds scary...

Answer (score 14):

**Meme**: Linking to [Welbog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog)

**Origin**: [jjnguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598) / [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) / [mmyers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13531/mmyers)

**Cultural Height**: Linking to [Welbog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend/10086#10086) never goes out of style, but technically late July, 2009

**Background**: Started by jjnguy with [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend/10082#10082), as a genuine recognition of Welbog's brilliance.  It was made into a meme by mmyers and Shog9 minutes later [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend/10088#10088) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend/10090#10090).

Comment: Pesto...I did it first just for the record...check the edit history.

Comment: Shog9 actually edited his post within the 5 min window to get the link in the post.

Comment: jjnguy: Don't just sit there fabricating lies to make yourself seem important; edit the answer to add those lies.  Jerk.

Comment: Fine, I didn't wanna edit it and make it seem like I'm making stuff up...but I'll fix it, hold on.

Comment: Fixed

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19507#19507

Comment: I have to upvote this answer because my name is mentioned. Also, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/134710#comment39571_19507) for another good link.

Answer (score 14):

**Meme**: Downvote, flag and move on

**Originator:** TBD

**Cultural Height:** TBD

**Description:** The response to most of "What should we do when a question is low quality" or "What should be the response for behavior x" or "What action should we take for answer y"

Answer (score 14):

**Meme:** Moderator paper bag

**Originator:** Martijn Pieters

**Cultural Height:** It was highlighted as a needed thing from this comment: [Why was I suspended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368092/why-was-i-suspended/368097#comment590855_368097) but seems to have only two instances (latter links)

**First Seen:** [Why was a proper flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344790/why-was-a-proper-flag-declined/344792#344792)

**Background:** Moderators have a tendency to fess up to their mistakes. They do so by wearing their paper bag of sadness.

**Other example:** [Why was I suspended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368092/why-was-i-suspended/368097#368097)

**Usage:** For moderators to use when they make a mistake and own up to it in a dignified matter

Comment: Maybe this can become a Winter Bash hat ...

Comment: *You've been awarded the Paper Bag! Wait. Did you screw something up?!* totally.

Answer (score 11):

**Meme**: SO Mafia

**Originator**: Unknown

**Cultural Height**: Throughout 2009

**Background**: Originally known as the TDWTF Mafia, the SO Mafia is a group of users led by [HE WHO SHALL NOT BE NAMED](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19482#19482) who hang around on IRC (#somafia on slashnet) deciding which users get to live or die. They quiet the voices by down-voting and closing anything they don't like, and editing everything else to bring it up to their "standards".

Comment: It should be pointed out this is not a meme, but whatever. There was a meme based on it a while ago. "It is a mafia not a cabal damn it!".

Comment: We are not a meme, we AN HERO.

Comment: (-1) not a meme (see definition in OP)

Comment: @Shog9: YOU DOWN VOTED THE MAFIA?? It is all over for you man. We will edit your every post and down vote you right to hell!

Comment: Isn't Shog9 in the mafia?

Comment: @Jon B: Not after this incident.  He's lucky not to have his status edited to "deceased".  There's no rolling back from concrete shoes.

Comment: @Shog9: Look out! You have been implicated with being in THE MAFIA! You will go down with us!

Comment: The trick to running the SO Mafia is sorting what voice is telling you what.

Comment: I always preferred Cabal to mafia.

Comment: @Gortok: That is why you were not in it. It is a **Mafia**.

Comment: How is this any different from the "Popular" kids in school manipulating groupthink through word and/or deed?  Add technology and a dash of meritocracy and we're back in high school.

Comment: @Kelly French, But that's what keeps it classy -- you see, they know better than us, and therefore must sometimes think **for** us, lest we lead ourselves astray.

Comment: @Dereleased, you seem to have extreme right tendencies (unless that comment's a joke, which it probably is `:)`).

Answer (score 11):

**Meme:** Brown

**Originator:** [jadarnel27](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168428/jadarnel27), in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=997641#997641) ([more](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=brown&Room=89&User=168428))

**Cultural Height:** TBD

**Background:** Brown. It's the answer to everything. Because brown.

**Usage:** Brown.

Comment: `#663300`​​​​​​

Comment: 6ff47afa5dc7daa42cc705a03fca8a9b

Comment: Also, `Because Science.`

Comment: But `Because Science` only works because brown.

Answer (score 9):

**Meme**: Vampire

**Origin**: Malfist

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: Vampire originally began as a tag on Stack Overflow when a user posted a question concerned over whether Jeff Atwood was of the blood-drinking undead. It has now been latched onto as an example of a completely nonsensical tag and is randomly inserted into the tags of equally nonsensical questions.

**Further Background**: Vampire was a tag that was used once upon a time. After Welbog's tragic loss of his powerful afro, he became fixated on adding this tag to any post he could to try and cope with his loss. Vampire may also refer to the coder of the night, Jeff Atwood.

**See Also**: A [Vampire picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17296/vote-to-delete-answers/17299#17299)

Comment: VAMPIRE VAMPIRE VAMPIRE VAMPIRE **VAMPIRE**

Comment: Don't forget the Jon Skeet files (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/pics/calling/)

Comment: @SLNaH Bunny Shoes?!?!?!

Comment: In a way, Vampire is SO's Obi-Wan Kenobi.

Comment: @SuperLongNamesareHilarious Woah!

Answer (score 9):

**Meme**: Profit

**Originator**: South Park

**First Used At Stack Exchange**: [Oct 9 '08](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5429/178816)

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: Used in various meta posts often in conjunction with "fun", whatever that is. Often used to add levity to an otherwise dull post (similar to Burninate requests being "witty").

> This meme comes directly from South Park‘s season 2, episode 17 (30th in total) which aired on December 16th, 1998. In this particular episode, the children’s underwear are being stolen from them by gnomes for the purpose of “profit.”
> The process, as explained by thee gnomes goes something like this.
> Step 1. Collect underpants.
> Step 2. ?
> Step 3. PROFIT

http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/profit

Answer (score 9):

**Meme:** Iterative shrug evolution

**Originator:** ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**Cultural Height:** ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**Background:** The shrug character requires additional care to be properly printed in a post, by escaping the backslash representing the right arm and escaping one of the underscores to prevent italics in posts already edited after the migration to [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark). This has led to multiple variations of the Unicode figure found on Stack Overflow posts.

- No escaping, missing right arm: ¯_(ツ)_/¯ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35217358)
- Unicode full width spacing underscore to avoid style rules: ¯\＿(ツ)＿/¯ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63300058)
- Shrunken arms and tilted head, more uncommon: ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64485764)
- Surrounded by a code box, so that no escaping is required: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`
- Beefy left arm, excessive number of slashes ¯\_(ツ)_//¯
- The final form, sometimes [after](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37987197/revisions) [correcting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50388890/revisions) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29013502/revisions): ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

More recently, multiple edits were required, hence the iterative evolution.

- [Iterative shrug evolution in a Stack Overflow chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/50807993/history)
- [Iterative shrug evolution on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/402448/revisions)

As stated in deleted comments, full consistency in the shrug character is deemed  important by some, and a new perspective for others.

> - [...] please do something about that shrug. Poor guy is missing an arm.
> - Thanks. So much better now. That hand flailing on the air was unnerving.
> - I don't know, it kinda reminded me of Rayman.
> - And know the little fella has two arms, and it's not inside a dark space. [...] There is hope for us still.

Comment: ¯\\_( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)_/¯

Answer (score 8):

**Meme:** Meta Meta Meta....

**Originator:** [Pollyanna](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2915/pollyanna)

**Cultural Height:** March 12th, 2010

**Background:** It was first fully realized with Pollyanna's posting of [Question Title That Doesn't Describe The Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem) it has since been regarded as the goto question for when you wish to talk about talking about talking about meta.

**Further Background:** It has existed before this question, but the tag has not existed and it was not as widespread.

Answer (score 8):

**Meme**: Z̭͙̳ͮ̐̂̆̍̒̚͢a͇̬̯̮̱̮̮͆ͯͣ͋ͬ̚l͒̂g͖͙̲̭͋ͫ̓́̚o͊́͏͉̫̮̬͍ͅ ̣̟̯͚͕͓̍ͯ͐ͬ̃͑t͇̤͈͓̺͎̍͗̄̂͂ͮ̑e̺̗͎̘̋̄̐̉͒x͈t̟̮͓͚̟̘̃ͮ̀͠

**Originator**: Unknown, possibly [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936)

**Cultural Height**: Taller than this.ͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦͦ

**Background**: Zalgo text wasn't widely known on Stack Overflow before [bobince got tired answering all the RegEx with HTML questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5958455). There are also other references to the Zalgo text like [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844/5958455) and [Zalgo in user names and effects on comments rendering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247022/350567).

Answer (score 8):

**Meme:** Wizards

**Originators:** [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859), [Ask a Question Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard)

**Cultural height:** As tall as the wizardry tower goes

**Background:** Shadow Wizard is one of the most prolific users here on Meta. While their name previously didn't hold that much significance, after another prolific Meta user, [Sonic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214), also adopted the word "Wizard" as part of their username (per their [normal cycle of changing usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26518/377214)), there began a trend where many other active Meta users adopted it as part of their usernames.

After the Ask a Question Wizard rolled out on Stack Overflow, more Meta users also adopted the word "Wizard" into their usernames.

Examples:

- [Sonic the Wizard Werehog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-wizard-werehog)
- [Pikachu the Purple Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/405220/pikachu-the-purple-wizard) (later [Pikachu the Watermelon Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/405220/pikachu-the-watermelon-wizard))
- [MEE the setup wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/364003/mee-the-setup-wizard)
- [a wizard arachnid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/388442/a-wizard-arachnid) (later [Add Printer Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/388442/add-printer-wizard))
- [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/302202/ask-question-wizard)
- [Get Answer Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241919/get-answer-wizard) (later [No Distraction Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241919/no-distraction-wizard))
- [Meta Bug Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/350567/meta-bug-wizard)
- [M.A.R. The Chemical Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/280934/m-a-r-the-chemical-wizard)
- [Shadow 10 Years Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-10-years-wizard)

Comment: True Wizardry! :-D

Comment: Seems like this was previously positively received, but started receiving a lot of downvotes after my recent edit. Should I roll it back?

Comment: Downvotes are likely by people not aware of the game Normal Human and Andrew play for years, and don't understand the last two are actual users. I'd say leave it be.

Comment: I liked this meme because it gave me an excuse to draw SE and SO as wizards :)

Comment: Characters have entered the chat.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "as high as the wizardry tower goes", as towers don't go tall?

Answer (score 8):

**Meme**: Whoops Wednesday / Whoopsie Wednesday

**Originator**: [Adam Lear](/users/155160)

**Cultural Height**: Every Wednesday

**Background**:
First mentioned in [a bug report about a TODO comment showing up on question pages](/a/375324/289905), this was labeled a “part of [the staffs’] new tradition here at Stack Overflow”.
The original refers to it as “Whoops Wednesday”, but in later mentions, it’s usually called “Whoopsie Wednesday” because it rolls off the tongue more easily.

Essentially, it’s a silly bug, a blunder, a [*whoopsie*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whoopsy#Noun) that happened to occur on a Wednesday.
The whimsical alliteration makes the phrase memorable.

**Referenced here**:

- [(Down)vote tooltip gets mixed-up with tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416118#comment895712_416118)
- [Cannot edit answer from review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416472#comment898629_416472)
- [Who is Samuel Ordonez and why are they a moderator here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376974)

Answer (score 7):

**Meme:** Option Strict On

**Originator:** VB.NET

**Cultural Height:** It's larger in need than it appears.

**Background:** [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline) wasn't too fussy about strict typing. You could add integers to strings and usually get the result you wanted. And *vice-versa*. ***Usually***. VB.NET promised to change that and let you get predictable results from your code. As in, the prediction *you* made, and not what the compiler felt like doing. But that promise is `Option`al, and not `Strict`ly `On` as the default.

**Corollary:** If your code does not compile after setting Option Strict On, it was faulty anyway.

**Caveat:** Without hours of delving through imprecise documentation, some things can only be found out at run-time. The increase in entropy of the universe for allowing run-time determination of types may be less than the entropy increase resulting from figuring out how to strongly-type something.

**Usage:** If someone asks a VB.NET question, look for something like `TextBox1.Text = x + 5`. Found it? Yes! Add a comment like "You should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to point out some problems in your code." Your work is done.

Comment: This sounds like a Stack Overflow meme, not a meta meme.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Wow, that was quick! How do I get it to SO memes instead? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think we have one, curiously enough. :/

Comment: @JeremyBanks I have a suspicion that this was born from MSO and had some transmogrification to MSE.

Comment: @JeremyBanks How on Earth did you manage [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PKVoO.png)?

Comment: @E.P. magic.... or just bug on your side. There's client side script updating comment time stamps on the fly, for some reason on your side it wasn't working very well. ;)

Comment: Of course, it should be pointed out this _is_ often the actual issue and _does_ need to be mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

**Meme**: `!!/blame`

**Originator**: [Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664) ([this commit](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/commit/336b7a378645cd38c5db568a8d84e3aa6e2d1b6b))

**Cultural Height**: Every time this command is being issued in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540) or [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89) or another chat room

**Background**: [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey) is a community-made chat bot that monitors new posts on the Stack Exchange network and filters out spam. It has a lot of commands that people can issue, among which are ones for joking or entertainment purposes, and `!!/blame` is [one of the most popular](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%21%21%2Fblame&room=11540) joke commands. Whenever someone issues this command in a chat room that Smokey resides in, it will respond with

> It's [someone]'s fault.

where `[someone]` will be a randomly chosen user that happens to be in the room at the moment (this includes SmokeDetector itself). It has since been [a popular entertainment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=s+fault&user=120914&room=11540), and [people star Smokey's response](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=s%20fault&Room=11540&User=120914&sort=stars) when it happens to blame an interesting user.

**Usage**: Drop into [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540) or [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89) and post a message of `!!/blame`, then watch [SmokeDetector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/120914)'s response.

Answer (score 7):

**Meme**: Roomba

**Origin**: Antiquity (or 2002, if [irobot.com](https://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/Company-Information.aspx) is to be believed)

**Cultural Height**: Fears of premature deletion in March 2013 ([this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171763/how-can-we-stop-premature-deletion)). Still discussed regularly on meta. A comment on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314065/why-is-the-script-for-deletion-called-roomba/314067#314067) by [Sebastian Simon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/289905/sebastian-simon) prompted this entry.

**Background**: A [Roomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roomba) is an automatic robotic vacuum cleaner for cleaning floors. The Stack Exchange auto-deletion script automatically deletes inactive posts that meet certain [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) and has thus become known as the Roomba. The implication is that sometimes users will find posts have been deleted while they have been away, much like a Roomba might clean a house.

Answer (score 6):

**Même:** *His Madnificents!* (alternate versions include Madnifiscents, Madnifisense, etc.)

**Originator:** [Ghanima](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/54/ghanima)

**Background:** It started when @Aurora0001 was [automatically added as room owner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34081630#34081630) of the IoT main chat room. He [started out his career](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34085984#34085984) saying,

> Say hello to your benevolent dictator of Internet of Things chat!

Ghanima [replied](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34086033#34086033) *right away* ([tm](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%28tm%29&Room=49682&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)):

> All hail to Aurora, first of his name, protector of the realm.

His message received exactly *[two stars,](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/49682?m=33988128#33988128)* and from there it simply escalated, to the point where [Ghanima posted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/49682?m=34114334#34114334),

> @Aurora0001 Praised be thee, oh Madnificence!

By some odd chance, the message failed to be starred, but the title has stuck. Only anonymous2's and Helmar's mod hammers () can keep *him* in check.

Comment: It's *right away* (tm) not immediately ;) coming to think of it *right away* should be a meme in its own right. Post it *right away*!

Comment: @Ghanima, you are right!  I've edited in the correction.

Answer (score 5):

**Meme**: You insensitive clod!

**Originator**: [sixlettervariables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162175/sixlettervariables)

**First Heard:** June 9, 2012

**Cultural Height**: TBD

**Background**: After a question was asked suggesting that Stack Overflow modify their logo for holidays and events, sixlettervariables suggested that an imagined response from users might be: "Omigerd you left out Important Day X you insensitive clods!"

**Related**:

- [Change logo theme according to important events/holidays?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135176/change-logo-theme-according-to-important-events-holidays),
- The Calvin And Hobbes comic strip responsible for [the original Slashdot Meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot#Culture):

[image: Calvin and Hobbes by Bill Watterson]

Comment: sorry, but it was sixlettervariables in the comments who Tim was quoting.

Comment: I'm _pretty_ sure this originated on Slashdot and just carried over. I had not read the comment cited here before inferring the same about George Edison under his answer on the same question :)

Comment: Originally a [Slashdot Meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot#Culture), does that matter? :-P

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a Slashdot meme, lots of people use it quite often. @Ben - you insensitive clod!

Comment: Hey! No C&H-rolling the meta meme post! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/134710#134710

Comment: I thought phrases had to be used more than once to become memes.

Answer (score 5):

**Meme:** Boom

**Originator:** That Evil Chatroom that Organises Votes (aka, the [SOCVR Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers))

**Cultural Height:** Early 2015-Mid 2016(ish?)

**Background:** Boom (or 'Booming') originated from the [SOCVR chat-room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), as a reply to someone requesting the closure of a question (primarily by using "cv-pls" [or "cv-plz", for the weak-minded]), that the question is now closed (or dealt with).

Comment: I'm sure this is something we stole from Tavern on the Meta chat room.

Comment: @gunr2171 And of course is now banned!

Comment: @DavidG because we can't have nice thingz ...

Comment: @rene 18 months to reply, nice!

Comment: Also edited 'cultural height' as this was banned like, what, two years ago now? ;-).

Answer (score 4):

**Meme**: Blog Onebox Shenanigans

**Originator**: Andrew

**Cultural Height**: Every time a blog post is posted and shared in [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) by Feeds.

**First Appearance**: [September 10, 2019](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7896571#7896571)

**Background**: At some point, oneboxing of blog posts started to break randomly. Andrew started replying to almost every Feeds message with a funny reply. ([list](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%40Feeds&Room=89&User=241919&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest))
Others joined the fray, but he stays the most loyal.

Comment: *[oneboxing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/onebox/info).* - *"A feature of Stack Exchange chat, "oneboxing", automatically inlines some links that are posted on a single line by themselves."*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum that is correct. What about it? The meme is about users behavior, i.e. what they do in response to the onebox. It's not the broken onebox itself.

Answer (score 3):

**Meme**: StackExchange™ Buggy Features™

**Originator**: Unknown, possibly badp

**Cultural Height**: Every time a StackExchange™ "Feature" Report™ comes up

**Background**: Starting with Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, there has been a culture of naming Wacky Features™ of Stack Exchange (i.e. design bugs) as trademarks. Examples:

- [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ sometimes links to the wrong page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68796)
- [Please add wildcard support to the StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69230)
- [Do not consider feed bots in the StackExchange™ MultiChannel ChatPreviewer™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67160)
- [Stack Exchange Aboutme Extender™ with code formatting on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316271)
- [Stack Exchange Usercard Squeezer™ on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316111/stack-exchange-usercard-squeezer-on-profile-page)

A variation of this meme is to use the name ".... Overflow™" (referring to Stack Overflow):

- [Character Overflow™ on profile page with long usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317193)
- [Underline Overflow™ in links under answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341868/underline-overflow-in-links-under-answers)
- [Warning Underflow™ in flag dialog for flag warning/ban messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344865/warning-underflow-in-flag-dialog-for-flag-warning-ban-messages)

> [image: feature]

**Related**: [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838)

Comment: According to Oxford Dictionaries, a **meme** is: *an element of a culture or system of behavior that may be considered to be passed from one individual to another by nongenetic means, especially imitation. //
a humorous image, video, piece of text, etc., that is copied (often with slight variations) and spread rapidly by Internet users.* Randomly tagging  a TM on a title doesn't make it a meme.

Answer (score 2):

**Meme:** Neckbeards

**Originator:** [user3184074](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/247661/user3184074) and "my forum websites"

**Cultural Height:** [ongoing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216015/reverseengineering-stackexchange-com-is-overflowing#comment698772_216015)

**First Seen:** https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215805/ (meta 10kers only)

**Background:** Some random guy typed up a page-long rant with copious amounts of allcaps and calling people "neckbeards," which is apparently [*(slang) A nerd; a dweeb.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neckbeard), although in the context he used it nobody is entirely sure what it means.

Answer (score -1):

**Meme:** [Oh! the huge Manatee!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbjm9.jpg)

**Originator:** The image already existed as a general Internet Meme, it was used first on a scared question by [voyager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130127/voyager).

**First Heard:** [*Stickers for non US residents?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/18454/revisions) on [Sep 17 '09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5ce256f0-8cb7-463b-8435-d1609de4bb89/view-source).

**Cultural Height:** It pops up every [now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/my-calm-rational-assessment-of-the-question-upvote-rep-gain-change-and-ensuing-g/42944#42944) [and](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23724/small-formatting-quirk-that-bothers-me#comment-49158) [then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52562/area-51-voting-reset-and-changes).

**Background:** ---

**Trivia:** ---.

Answer (score -7):

**Meme:** gjlhglhfh

**Originator:** Unknown

**Cultural height:** TBD

**Background:** Whenever somebody suggests making comments mandatory with downvotes, a common argument against it is that people will just comment “gjlhglhfh” or some other random combination of characters to explain their downvote.

Comment: Not sure if this argument really qualifies as a “meme”.

Comment: @SebastianSimon probably not..

Comment: It's too sad to be a meme @SebastianSimon

Comment: gjlhglhfhgjlhglhfh

Comment: Using the first three keys in that row, "A", "S", and "D", e.g. "adasdasdasd", is much more common.

Comment: gjlhglhfhgjlhglhfhgjlhglhfhgjlhglhfh

Answer (score -9):

**Meme**: *grabs/gets popcorn*

**Originator**: Unknown

**First Seen**: [December 3<sup>rd</sup>, 2010](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=290738#290738)

**Cultural Height**: As long as there is drama somewhere

**Background**: Chat meme. Whenever a drama is about to begin, or is ongoing, anyone can grab some popcorn and watch the drama folding before their eyes.

Comment: Is this Stack Exchange specific?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Stack Exchange chat is the only place I've seen it used, so can't really know for sure.

Comment: https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/popcorn-gifs

Comment: @Randal'Thor "Added 4 years ago"...  the SE chat usage predates that. Who said it didn't spark the meme elsewhere? Anyway.... even if non-SE meme that is often used in SE, think it might fit here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, grabbing popcorn to watch the drama *long* pre-dates Stack Exchange.  I saw it as a sight gag in a webcomic about 20 years ago, and it was an old idea even then.